# Is there a way to tell Chrome to save passwords by fieldname?

Tags: google-chrome, passwords, save

I'm creating a website and I got 2 forms on the first page : Login & Registration.

When I authenticate, Chrome asks me to save my password.
If I do so, when I get back on that page, Google Chrome auto fill my login informations on the Login form but also on the registration form.
The "login" fields on the Login and Registration forms have two different names and IDs.

It seems that Chrome auto fill the login and password informations every time it finds an input field with the password type.

I could use "autocomplete=off" on my password field ( on the Registration form ), but this behavior of Chrome seems weird.

So my question is :

Is there a way to tell Chrome to save the login & passwords informations based on the field name and not just the type ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered placing login and registration form on different web pages?

Comment: I could but this is a choice I've made, the design of the page had already been done so I can't get back. Surely not for such a small "bug" if I can call it like that.

Comment: have you tested behaviour of other web browsers? IE, firefox, opera? Since it is possible this is not just a Chrome question, but a more general one.

Comment: I tested with Firefox, it's the same bahavior indeed. I think I have no other choice than add autocomplete="off" on my registration fields.

Comment: There is a problem with autocomplete="off" too in Chrome - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374442/chrome-browser-ignoring-autocomplete-off