# Chrome ignores autocomplete="off"

Tags: html, google-chrome, autocomplete, forms

I've created a web application which uses a tagbox drop down. This works great in all browsers except Chrome browser (Version 21.0.1180.89).

Despite both the `input` fields AND the `form` field having the `autocomplete="off"` attribute, Chrome insists on showing a drop down history of previous entries for the field, which is obliterating the tagbox list.

Comment: Technically this question was asked about 5 months before the one referenced as "This question already has an answer here". That one is the duplicate as it came after this one.

Comment: Honestly, what if this is the reasoning for disabling autocomplete=off. What if, the plan is to make sure the web is detailed and described so that the browser you are using right now may autocomplete whatever field their latest version might want to. If that was the case, we need to describe all fields - and the browser will gracefully disable autocomplete for all fields that are outside the scope of the autocomplete script / app... Im betting on this being the case,

Comment: 7 years and still we can't disable autocomplete properly... such a shame..

Comment: @user3071434 and that answer is useless because it doesn't work.

Comment: i got explanation here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion

Comment: Try https://github.com/terrylinooo/disableautofill.js

Comment: I hate website that won't let my browser autocomplete

Comment: see https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=370363#c7 link that recommend use autocomplete="new-password"

Comment: Didn't want to add another "answer" to all of this so just going to comment but after trying so so so many solutions on our vuejs app search filter, I settled with this because chrome seems to respect this:   $("input[type='search']").wrapAll("<form autocomplete='off' />");

Comment: as of 31/12/2022, the solution "new-password" seems to be adaptable to any registered form data inside Chromium based browsers : for example if you add autocomplete="new-user-street-address-email-password-phone" to your form as attribute, the corresponding data will not be autocompleted.

Answer (score 462):

Prevent autocomplete of username (or email) and password:

```html
<input type="email" name="email"><!-- Can be type="text" -->
<input type="password" name="password" autocomplete="new-password">
```

---

Prevent autocomplete a field (**might not work**):

```html
<input type="text" name="field" autocomplete="nope">
```

**Explanation:**

`autocomplete` still works on an `<input>`despite having `autocomplete="off"`, but you can change `off` to a random string, like `nope`.

---

Others *"solutions"* for disabling the autocomplete of a field (it's not the right way to do it, but it works):

1.

**HTML:**

```html
<input type="password" id="some_id" autocomplete="new-password">
```

**JS (onload):**

```js
(function() {
    var some_id = document.getElementById('some_id');
    some_id.type = 'text';
    some_id.removeAttribute('autocomplete');
})();
```

or using **jQuery:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var some_id = $('#some_id');
    some_id.prop('type', 'text');
    some_id.removeAttr('autocomplete');
});
```

---

2.

**HTML:**

```html
<form id="form"></form>
```

**JS (onload):**

```js
(function() {
    var input = document.createElement('INPUT');
    input.type = 'text';
    document.getElementById('form').appendChild(input);
})();
```

or using **jQuery:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('<input>', {
        type: 'text'
    }).appendTo($('#form'));
});
```

---

To add more than one field using jQuery:

```js
function addField(label) {
  var div = $('<div>');
  var input = $('<input>', {
    type: 'text'
  });
  
  if(label) {
    var label = $('<label>', {
      text: label
    });
    
    label.append(input);
    div.append(label);    
  } else {
    div.append(input);    
  }  
  
  div.appendTo($('#form'));
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  addField();
  addField('Field 1: ');  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form"></form>
```

---

**Works in:**

- Chrome: 49+
- Firefox: 44+

Comment: Theres no code, just how does your answer actually prevent autocomplete if autocomplete="" is supposed to just accept a boolean

Comment: autocomplete="new-password" when assigned to the password field, worked for me in chrome.  autocomplete="off" on the form did not.

Comment: The most important (and only thing that worked for me) was absolutely ensuring your ID and Name property of your <input> field did not contain "Username" or "Password". This effectively stopped all autocomplete for me on autocomplete="off".

Comment: `new-password` is a good catch for any hidden input that's actually is not a password, thanks

Comment: Lol `autocomplete="nope"` actually worked for me, unless I add it to both my form fields. Like I can have it on either field and then _that_ field won't autocomplete, but the other field will still autocomplete, but soon as I put it on both fields, both of them starts autocompleting again.

Comment: The remark 'use a random string' made me think. And what indeed worked for me is a truly random string, via a function, every time the form is loaded, for example: `autocomplete="UwzM6"`.

Comment: lol autocomplete="nope" works well. Very funny though

Comment: time to start entering funny lines of text into autocomplete tags

Comment: For me helps autocomplete="new-password" in input type="password". Without using  jQuery or JS.

Comment: nope worked for me

Comment: "nope" worked for me, but I don't think it is true that it can be something random. I tried "no thank you" and then Chrome still gave suggestions...

Comment: Actual LOL. "nope" worked for me too. So HTML can just f "off"!

Comment: Great answer and multiple uses of the same unrecognised value seem to work now - so not sure if something has changed in Chrome since the comment from @SeriousLee. Just one suggestion - use a value such as `autocomplete="stopchrome"` to give other developers a hint about why it has been set in this way.

Answer (score 331):

**UPDATE**

It seems now Chrome ignores the `style="display: none;"` or `style="visibility: hidden;` attributes.

You can change it to something like:

```
<input style="opacity: 0;position: absolute;">
<input type="password" style="opacity: 0;position: absolute;">
```

In my experience, Chrome only autocompletes the first `<input type="password">` and the previous `<input>`. So I've added:

```html
<input style="display:none">
<input type="password" style="display:none">
```

To the top of the `<form>` and the case was resolved.

Comment: this not work anymore chrome 40 not work this solution

Comment: Not only is this ugly, but I still **can't** find any explanation to the **Why** question??

Comment: It seems Chrome now ignores them if display: none is used, so I moved the fields out of the view with absolute positioning...

Comment: `display: none;` will disappear the element, nothing about the autocomplete.

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger Why? Because Chrome abusively forces developer to do this because they don't respect the spec and don't want anybody to disable their terrible autofill that never gets the fields right :sigh:

Answer (score 174):

It appears that Chrome now ignores `autocomplete="off"` unless it is on the `<form autocomplete="off">` tag.

Comment: For React use 'autoComplete=off.'

Comment: For an explanation of _why_ Chrome made this change, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39689037/1766230 -- They prioritize users over developers.

Comment: If you would like to provide the Chrome team with valid reasons for using autocomplete="off" please do so here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=587466

Comment: @Digggid Chrome 71 doesn't ignore the attribute, but in some cases it ignores the "off" value. Using a value like "country" still works for me.

Comment: for Chrome 74 version. "autocomplete =off" works fine.

Comment: Just a clarification on the above as there are conflicting reports. On the form tag add autocomplete="off" and on the individual input tags add autocomplete="new-password". Working as of Chrome 75

Comment: Hi guys, I don't know why, but you could put  that's attribute autocomplete="new-password" and it works fine. For more details access https://www.codementor.io/leonardofaria/disabling-autofill-in-chrome-zec47xcui

Comment: As  Chrome 81, it now ignores `autocomplete="new-password"` on individual fields

Comment: I can confirm <form autocomplete="off"> still works on Chrome 88.0.4324.182.  I was having this issue with an INPUT whenever the part of the page is re-rendered.  The problem went away after I surrounded it with the form element.

Answer (score 158):

**2021 UPDATE:**
Change *<input type="text">* to **<input type="search" autocomplete="off" >**

That is all. Keeping the below answer around for nostalgia.

---

For a reliable workaround, you can add this code to your layout page:

```html
<div style="display: none;">
 <input type="text" id="PreventChromeAutocomplete" 
  name="PreventChromeAutocomplete" autocomplete="address-level4" />
</div>
```

Chrome respects autocomplete=off only when there is at least one other input element in the form with any other autocomplete value.

This will not work with password fields--those are handled very differently in Chrome. See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=468153 for more details.

**UPDATE: Bug closed as "Won't Fix" by Chromium Team March 11, 2016. See last comment in [my originally filed bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=468153#c164), for full explanation. TL;DR: use semantic autocomplete attributes such as autocomplete="new-street-address" to avoid Chrome performing autofill.**

Comment: @Jonathan Cowley-Thom: try these test pages I put up containing my workaround. On https://hub.securevideo.com/Support/AutocompleteOn, you should see Chrome autocomplete suggestions. Then, try the same entries on https://hub.securevideo.com/Support/AutocompleteOff. You should not see Chrome autocomplete suggestions. I just tested this on Chrome 45.0.2454.101m and 46.0.2490.71m, and it worked as expected on both.

Comment: One more update on this matter: I just received a notification from the Chrome team that this has been fixed. So, hopefully this workaround will very soon no longer be needed!

Comment: See my post above: "This will not work with password fields--those are handled very differently in Chrome. See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=468153 for more details."

Comment: Is there a link or a list of these "semantic autocomplete attributes"... but this seems to be the best answer.

Comment: Now I would recommend to change <input type="text"> to <input type="search">

Comment: Small tip: This bug (_yes bug regardless what they say in bug answers where they ignore standards_) is very unpleasant if you want to replace third party component input with your input and this behaviour is overlapping your functionality, for example DatePicker(s) for React. In this case just do not fill `id` of the input or fill it with `id = lastNumber+1` to keep it unique.
Tip 2: this bug is not Chrome bug but Chromium bug and it's the same in multiple browsers based on Chromium. Vivaldi for example.

Comment: @J.T.Taylor One must also have the `autocomplete="off"` attribute or the `type="search"` won't do the trick. *Thanks!* for finding *the trick*.

Comment: Changing the input type to search is NOT useful in cases like type="tel".

Comment: This. Changing value from `autocomplete="off"` to `autocomplete="something-else"` should do the trick.

Answer (score 123):

## Modern Approach

Simply make your input `readonly`, and on focus, remove it. This is a very simple approach and browsers will not populate `readonly` inputs. Therefore, this method is accepted and will never be overwritten by future browser updates.

```html
<input type="text" onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');" readonly />
```

The next part is optional. Style your input accordingly so that it does not look like a `readonly` input.

```css
input[readonly] {
     cursor: text;
     background-color: #fff;
}
```

[**WORKING EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/w0wxy9ao/)

Comment: @Basit - And that's why I called it a `modern approach`. Less than 1% of users in the world have Javascript turned off. So honestly, it's not worth anyones time accommodating for such a small audience when a large majority of websites rely on Javascript. Been developing websites for a very long time now, and 100% of my sites use Javascript and rely on it heavily. If users have Javascript turned off, that's their own problem and choice, not mine. They'll be unable to visit or use at least 90% of websites online with it turned off... Your downvote is completely irrelevant.

Comment: This does not work today in 49. Chrome "developers" is watching stackoverflow solutions and removing them.

Comment: @puchu - I'm using Chrome 49 and it's working perfectly fine? Use the following example, enter in a username and password, click 'Submit', save them to your Chrome saved credentials, reload the page, and you will notice that they are not auto filled - http://jsfiddle.net/w0wxy9ao/18/

Comment: This answer from September 2015 is basically a copy from the answer in November 2014 down below.

Comment: This breaks HTML form checks for `mandatory`. E.g. a password field using this code cannot be forced to be filled before submitting.

Comment: Remember that relying on JS on key interactions does not only break the feature for users who deactivated the JS: it also breaks it for those with slow connection (JS is not loaded yet).

Comment: Worked for me on chrome 81

Comment: Too bad. Sounded like such a smart idea. But stupid Chrome Version 84.0.4147.105 does not give a damn about it.

Comment: Not good because it just works only for once! In my case, when I click the button textbox is automatically filled. So if I make it as readonly it works only for once. Initial input readonly, click button, that's good text box is not filled. When click the text box readonly is set as false and text box working good as well. But When I click the button again, then text box is filled again because it is not readonly anymore, because we removed it on focus. So Every button click on my page I need to say, go make textbox readonly. So it doesn't seems a good solution...

Comment: Wow man, a lot of answers but this is the best one so far.

Comment: This worked for me, BUT I had to use `click` for `addEventListener()` because `focus` would still show the autocomplete

Comment: I can't believe this hack is the only thing that worked for me. I had a search input with autocomplete off, nothing worked. This is so messed up.

Answer (score 68):

**TL;DR:** Tell Chrome that this is a new password input and it won't provide old ones as autocomplete suggestions:

```
<input type="password" name="password" autocomplete="new-password">
```

---

`autocomplete="off"` doesn't work due to a design decision - lots of research shows that users have much longer and harder to hack passwords if they can store them in a browser or password manager.

The specification for `autocomplete` [has changed](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#autofill), and now supports various values to make login forms easy to auto complete:

```
<!-- Auto fills with the username for the site, even though it's email format -->
<input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="username">

<!-- current-password will populate for the matched username input  -->
<input type="password" autocomplete="current-password" />
```

If you *don't* provide these Chrome still tries to guess, and when it does it ignores `autocomplete="off"`.

The solution is that `autocomplete` values also exist for password reset forms:

```
<label>Enter your old password:
    <input type="password" autocomplete="current-password" name="pass-old" />
</label>
<label>Enter your new password:
    <input type="password" autocomplete="new-password" name="pass-new" />
</label>
<label>Please repeat it to be sure:
    <input type="password" autocomplete="new-password" name="pass-repeat" />
</label>
```

You can use this `autocomplete="new-password"` flag to tell Chrome not to guess the password, even if it has one stored for this site.

Chrome can also manage passwords for sites directly using the [credentials API](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/credential-management-api), which is a standard and will probably have universal support eventually.

Comment: Not a really compelling reason. The fact that the user wants something doesn't mean it is a smart idea. That's almost as bad as saying you will allow single character passwords in your application because the user finds it more convenient. At times, security trumps convenience...

Comment: I have a field called "ContactNoAlt" that Chrome insists on filling with an EmailAddress. Autocomplete on/off is preferred but a work-around is needed on a practical level because Chrome is falible. More pointedly autocomplete="off" is a standard - so what makes the developers of Chrome so good that they just feel they can ignore standards - perhaps one day Chrome will decide some other piece of HTML is inconvenient .... (this is starting to feel like IE5/6 de-ja-vu)

Comment: I'm a chrome user, and I don't want this behaviour. It didn't even ask me before it autofilled the password box that was popping up to make sure only I could access the web application concerned. Saving *some* passwords shouldn't mean autocompleting *all* passwords.

Comment: This answer (and Googles behaviour) ignore the fact that one of the major reasons you might want to do this is to implement your own (e.g, list from database) autocompletion behaviours.

Comment: you are trying to defend a clearly bad decision made by chrome. I am implementing the company's policy which I cannot change. So now I have to insert hacks for chrome. They currently work. If they will stop working then our company will change the default browser for employees. So now we have the same behaviour but with hacks and possibly broken pages in future upgrades. And seeing all these answers here there are a lot of devs using these hacks. Well done chrome.

Comment: autocomplete="new-password" doesn't disable suggestions but only autofill. Suggestions are still show upon focus. How do we totally turn of suggestions without implmeneting our own type="password" ?!

Comment: @Cesar `autocomplete="new-password"` was only ever a hack - it was the best workaround in 2017, but as I said in the original post (rightly or wrongly) the Chrome team _want_ to make passwords auto-completable. `type="password"` tells the browser to treat this as a password - if you want to have an obscured input that shouldn't be treated as passwords (i.e. not found by password managers) then yeah, the only reliable way to do it will be to roll your own.

Answer (score 62):

Well, a little late to the party, but it seems that there is a bit of misunderstanding about how `autocomplete` should and shouldn't work. According to the HTML specifications, the user agent (in this case Chrome) can override `autocomplete`:

https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#autofilling-form-controls:-the-autocomplete-attribute

> A user agent may allow the user to override an element's autofill field name, e.g. to change it from "off" to "on" to allow values to be remembered and prefilled despite the page author's objections, or to always "off", never remembering values. However, user agents should not allow users to trivially override the autofill field name from "off" to "on" or other values, as there are significant security implications for the user if all values are always remembered, regardless of the site's preferences.

So in the case of Chrome, the developers have essentially said "we will leave this to the user to decide in their preferences whether they want `autocomplete` to work or not. If you don't want it, don't enable it in your browser".

However, it appears that this is a little over-zealous on their part for my liking, but it is the way it is. The specification also discusses the potential security implications of such a move:

> The "off" keyword indicates either that the control's input data is particularly sensitive (for example the activation code for a nuclear weapon); or that it is a value that will never be reused (for example a one-time-key for a bank login) and the user will therefore have to explicitly enter the data each time, instead of being able to rely on the UA to prefill the value for him; or that the document provides its own autocomplete mechanism and does not want the user agent to provide autocompletion values.

So after experiencing the same frustration as everyone else, I found a solution that works for me. It is similar in vein to the `autocomplete="false"` answers.

A Mozilla article speaks to exactly this problem:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion

> In some case, the browser will keep suggesting autocompletion values even if the autocomplete attribute is set to off. This unexpected behavior can be quite puzzling for developers. The trick to really force the no-completion is to assign a random string to the attribute

So the following code *should* work:

```
autocomplete="nope"
```

And so should each of the following:

```
autocomplete="false"
autocomplete="foo"
autocomplete="bar"
```

The issue I see is that the browser agent might be smart enough to learn the `autocomplete` attribute and apply it next time it sees the form. If it does do this, the only way I can see to still get around the problem would be to dynamically change the `autocomplete` attribute value when the page is generated.

One point worth mentioning is that many browser will ignore `autocomplete` settings for login fields (username and password). As the Mozilla article states:

> For this reason, many modern browsers do not support autocomplete="off" for login fields.
>
> - If a site sets autocomplete="off" for a form, and the form includes username and password input fields, then the browser will still offer to remember this login, and if the user agrees, the browser will autofill those fields the next time the user visits this page.
> - If a site sets autocomplete="off" for username and password input fields, then the browser will still offer to remember this login, and if the user agrees, the browser will autofill those fields the next time the user visits this page.
>
> This is the behavior in Firefox (since version 38), Google Chrome (since 34), and Internet Explorer (since version 11).

Finally a little info on whether the attribute belongs on the `form` element or the `input` element. The spec again has the answer:

> If the autocomplete attribute is omitted, the default value corresponding to the state of the element's form owner's autocomplete attribute is used instead (either "on" or "off"). If there is no form owner, then the value "on" is used.

So. Putting it on the form should apply to all input fields. Putting it on an individual element should apply to just that element (even if there isn't one on the form). If `autocomplete` isn't set at all, it defaults to `on`.

**Summary**

To disable `autocomplete` on the whole form:

```
<form autocomplete="off" ...>
```

Or if you dynamically need to do it:

```
<form autocomplete="random-string" ...>
```

To disable `autocomplete` on an individual element (regardless of the form setting being present or not)

```
<input autocomplete="off" ...>
```

Or if you dynamically need to do it:

```
<input autocomplete="random-string" ...>
```

And remember that certain user agents can override even your hardest fought attempts to disable `autocomplete`.

Comment: @user2060451 - what doesn't work? I just tested it in 76.0.3809.87 on Windows and Mac. - both perform as per the spec. as described above. If you could provide a little more description than "does not work" I may be able to help you out.

Comment: I just tried to give (from console after everything loaded and in set it on server side) a random string for autocomplete of input element, it did not work. Giving autocomplete="off" to form element also did not work.

Comment: It works with random string. From what I noticed, it seems that no matter what attribute value you put, chrome will save it. So if you put "off", chrome will think that "off" is equal to the value you entered. The next time you have a form with "off", chrome will reuse that last value. Using a random value fix that problem, because if the value is new and unique each time, chrome will have never seen it and won't suggest anything.

Comment: Does not work any better than setting `new-password`

Comment: @pishpish - The OP's question didn't mention anything about password fields and was directed at a `select` tag which implies that it was not a password field they were having problems with (although it could have been a problem field too). Moreover, `new-password` is a hint in the spec, and browsers may or may not follow it for password fields only. So don't be surprised if `new-password` doesn't always work for password fields in every case.

Answer (score 53):

### Always working solution

I've solved the endless fight with Google Chrome with the use of random characters. When you always render autocomplete with random string, it will never remember anything.

```
<input name="name" type="text" autocomplete="rutjfkde">
```

Hope that it will help to other people.

**Update 2022:**

Chrome made this improvement: `autocomplete="new-password"` which will solve it but I am not sure, if Chrome change it again to different functionality after some time.

Comment: When every render will have uniq random string, its impossible remember. Thant`t the point.

Comment: This didn't work for me in chrome version 99.0.4844.51 on email and password fields, but this did: autocomplete="new-password" Found on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion

Comment: not work for me too

Comment: autocomplete="new-password" works for chrome version-105.0.5195.127

Comment: think carefully before answering something you can't control

Comment: thanks mano, the only one that worked

Answer (score 43):

The solution at present is to use `type="search"`. Google doesn't apply autofill to inputs with a type of search.

See: https://twitter.com/Paul_Kinlan/status/596613148985171968

*Update 04/04/2016:* Looks like this is fixed! See http://codereview.chromium.org/1473733008

Comment: this is not true as v73

Comment: This was the easiest thing for me, chrome version 98.0.4758.102. Seems to tenuous whether it'll work for other versions of Chrome though.

Answer (score 28):

**Browser does not care about autocomplete=off auto or even fills credentials to wrong text field?**

I fixed it by setting the password field to read-only and activate it, when user clicks into it or uses tab-key to this field.

**fix browser autofill in: readonly and set writeble on focus** (at mouse click and tabbing through fields)

```
 <input type="password" readonly  
     onfocus="$(this).removeAttr('readonly');"/>
```

Update:
Mobile Safari sets cursor in the field, but does not show virtual keyboard. New Fix works like before but handles virtual keyboard:

```
<input id="email" readonly type="email" onfocus="if (this.hasAttribute('readonly')) {
    this.removeAttribute('readonly');
    // fix for mobile safari to show virtual keyboard
    this.blur();    this.focus();  }" />
```

Live Demo https://jsfiddle.net/danielsuess/n0scguv6/

// UpdateEnd

By the way, *more information* on my observation:

Sometimes I notice this strange behavior on Chrome and Safari, when there are password fields in *the same form.* I guess, the browser looks for a password field to insert your saved credentials. Then it **autofills *username* into the nearest textlike-input field , that appears prior the password field** in DOM (just guessing due to observation). As the browser is the last instance and you can not control it, *sometimes even autocomplete=off would not prevent to fill in credentials* into wrong fields, but not user or nickname field.

Comment: rather than using onfocus, I use a setTimeout to clear the readonly, so my users don't see the input is read only and never focus it!

Comment: Only solution works for me

Answer (score 27):

Chrome version 34 now ignores the `autocomplete=off`, 
[see this](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2014/04/09/chrome_makes_new_password_grab_in_version_34/).

[Lots of discussion](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/msg/security-dev/wYGThW5WRrE/qiWrKwJ79S4J) on whether this is a good thing or a bad thing? Whats your views?

Comment: sorry for the downvote ... this is not a discussion site (try quora instead), and you don't provide an answer. Thanks for the link though.

Answer (score 25):

You can use `autocomplete="new-password"`

```html
<input type="email" name="email">
<input type="password" name="password" autocomplete="new-password">
```

Works in:

- Chrome: 53, 54, 55
- Firefox: 48, 49, 50

Comment: This can not work, because autocomplete string is fixed. Browsers will remember new-password for next time.

Answer (score 17):

> [Works in 2021 for Chrome(v88, 89, 90), Firefox, Brave, Safari]
>
> The old answers already written here will work with trial and error, but most of
> them don't link to any official doc or what Chrome has to say on this
> matter.

The issue mentioned in the question is because of Chrome's autofill feature, and here is Chrome's stance on it in this bug link - https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=468153#c164

To put it simply, there are two cases -

- ***[CASE 1]***: Your `input` type is something other than `password`. In this case, the solution is simple, and has three steps.

  - Add `name` attribute to `input`
  - `name` should not start with a value like email or username, otherwise Chrome still ends up showing the dropdown. For example, `name="emailToDelete"` shows the dropdown, but `name="to-delete-email"` doesn't. Same applies for `autocomplete` attribute.
  - Add `autocomplete` attribute, and add a value which is meaningful for you, like `new-field-name`

  It will look like this, and you won't see the autofill for this input again for the rest of your life -

  ```
  <input type="text/number/something-other-than-password" name="x-field-1" autocomplete="new-field-1" />
  ```
- ***[CASE 2]***: `input` `type` is `password`

  - Well, in this case, irrespective of your trials, Chrome will show you the dropdown to manage passwords / use an already existing password. Firefox will also do something similar, and same will be the case with all other major browsers. [1]
  - In this case, if you really want to stop the user from seeing the dropdown to manage passwords / see a securely generated password, you will have to play around with JS to switch input type, as mentioned in the other answers of this question.

[1] A detailed MDN doc on turning off autocompletion - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion

Comment: This isn't working. I have a WordPress site with inputs for username and password. For the username input I have `<input name="portal_user" type="text" maxlength="64" autocomplete="portal">`. Chrome insists on autofilling the WordPress admin username and password.

Comment: Hi @Gavin, that's why I answered by taking two separate cases. Please have a look at the second case that I wrote. There is no direct way to disable the autofill for password. MDN has a good doc on this. That's the hard truth!

For username, it should ideally work. Also, by autofill, I, or any browser to be precise, is talking about the dropdown that comes up with a saved list. Are you talking of autocomplete by any chance? Will be glad to help you resolve the issue :)

Answer (score 14):

`Autocomplete="Off"` doesn't work anymore.

Try using just a random string instead of `"Off"`, for example `Autocomplete="NoAutocomplete"`

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 13):

I am posting this answer to bring an updated solution to this problem.
I am currently using Chrome 49 and no given answer work for this one.
I am also looking for a solution working with other browsers and previous versions.

Put this code on the beginning of your form

```
<div style="display: none;">
    <input type="text" autocomplete="new-password">
    <input type="password" autocomplete="new-password">
</div>
```

Then, for your real password field, use

```
<input type="password" name="password" autocomplete="new-password">
```

Comment this answer if this is no longer working or if you get an issue with another browser or version.

Approved on:

- Chrome : 49
- Firefox : 44, 45
- Edge : 25
- Internet Explorer : 11

Comment: Unfortunately, Chrome version 49.0.2623.87 and it does not work for TextBox, I still see autocomplete poping up.

Answer (score 11):

Seen chrome ignore the `autocomplete="off"`, I solve it with a stupid way which is using "fake input" to cheat chrome to fill it up instead of filling the "real" one.

**Example:**

```
<input type="text" name="username" style="display:none" value="fake input" /> 
<input type="text" name="username" value="real input"/>
```

Chrome will fill up the "fake input", and when submit, server will take the "real input" value.

Answer (score 11):

No clue why this worked in my case, but on chrome I used `autocomplete="none"` and Chrome stopped suggesting addresses for my text field.

Comment: confirmed with Chrome 86.0 /Nov 2020

Answer (score 10):

`autocomplete="off"` is usually working, but not always. It depends on the `name` of the input field. Names like "address", 'email', 'name' - will be autocompleted (browsers think they help users), when fields like "code", "pin" - will not be autocompleted (if `autocomplete="off"` is set)

My problems was - autocomplete was messing with google [address helper](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform)

I fixed it by renaming it

from

```
<input type="text" name="address" autocomplete="off">
```

to

```
<input type="text" name="the_address" autocomplete="off">
```

Tested in chrome 71.

Comment: I think this is the latest way to remove auto complete. working in 2020 May on chrome 81

Answer (score 10):

Writing a 2020+ answer in case if this helps anyone. I tried many combinations above, though there is one key that was missed in my case. Even though I had kept autocomplete="nope" a random string, it didn't work for me because I had **name** attribute **missing**!

so I kept name='password'
and autocomplete = "new-password"

for username, I kept name="usrid" // DONT KEEP STRING THAT CONTAINS 'user'

and autocomplete = "new-password" // Same for it as well, so google stops suggesting password (manage password dropdown)

this worked very well for me.
(I did this for Android and iOS web view that Cordova/ionic uses)

```
<ion-input [type]="passwordType" name="password" class="input-form-placeholder" formControlName="model_password"
        autocomplete="new-password" [clearInput]="showClearInputIconForPassword">
</ion-input>
```

Comment: This solution still works as of 3 Feb 2021 - tested on latest Chrome, Firefox and IE11. Random string in autocomplete doesn't work.

Comment: glad to know that :)

Comment: this works well in latest Chrome 27/11/2021 - do not use name="email" either

Answer (score 9):

to anyone looking for a solution to this, I finally figure it out.

Chrome only obey's the `autocomplete="off"` if the page is a HTML5 page (I was using XHTML).

I converted my page to HTML5 and the problem went away (facepalm).

Comment: can you explain how you did this?

Comment: @user1130176 It's 2021, unless you specifically set out not to use HTML5, you are using HTML5. This solution, if it ever was one, is no longer relevant.

Answer (score 9):

Some end 2020 Update. I tried all the old solutions from different sites. None of them worked! :-(

Then I found this:

Use

```
<input type="search"/>
```

and the autocomplete is gone!

Success with Chrome 86, FireFox, Edge 87.

Comment: browsers will add styling to the input and make it clearable

Answer (score 9):

**Update 08/2022:**

I managed to get autocomplete to be respected by including

```
autocomplete="new-password"
```

on each individual input element regardless of type.

E.g.

```
<input id="email" type="email" autocomplete="new-password"/>
```

Comment: A 10 year old question, still relevant every couple of months.

Comment: I know right... haha

Comment: Chrome team is intentionally divisive. Just give developers the ability to strategically turn off autocomplete already! Instead, people create hacky hacks that work temporarily. All these answers are proof of the absurdity. After 10 years, it's clear they don't listen to feedback.

Answer (score 8):

`autocomplete=off` is largely ignored in modern browsers - primarily due to password managers etc.

You can try adding this `autocomplete="new-password"` it's not fully supported by all browsers, but it works on some

Answer (score 7):

Quick hack, Incase if you still getting the autocomplete even though reading above answers, you can try this. Giving random string will remove the autocomplete.

```
<input autocomplete="somerandomstring" or autocomplete="disabled">
```

Idk is it right way or not, It just worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

Change input type attribute to `type="search"`.

Google doesn't apply auto-fill to inputs with a type of search.

Comment: I'll downvote: tested on chrome 60: this doesn't prevent autocomplete..

Answer (score 6):

Up until just this last week, the two solutions below appeared to work for Chrome, IE and Firefox. But with the release of Chrome version 48 (and still in 49), they no longer work:

1. The following at the top of the form:

```html
<input style="display:none" type="text" name="fakeUsername"/>
<input style="display:none" type="password" name="fakePassword"/>
```

2. The following in the password input element:

   autocomplete="off"

So to quickly fix this, at first I tried to use a major hack of initially setting the password input element to disabled and then used a setTimeout in the document ready function to enable it again.

```
setTimeout(function(){$('#PasswordData').prop('disabled', false);}, 50);
```

But this seemed so crazy and I did some more searching and found @tibalts answer in [Disabling Chrome Autofill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill/29582380#29582380). His answer is to use autocomplete="new-password" in the passwords input and this appears to work on all browsers (I have kept my fix number 1 above at this stage).

Here is the link in the Google Chrome developer discussion:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=370363#c7

Comment: @JorgeSampayo Only works on password inputs but not on text inputs.

Comment: Why would anyone want to disable autocomplete on username/password fields? Not a surprise that browser manufacturers are ignoring autocomplete more and more.

Let your users use password managers. This should be *encouraged* not prevented for everyone’s security.

Answer (score 5):

After the chrome v. 34, setting `autocomplete="off"` at `<form>` tag doesn`t work

I made the changes to avoid this annoying behavior:

1. Remove the `name` and the `id` of the password input
2. Put a class in the input (ex.: `passwordInput` )

(So far, Chrome wont put the saved password on the input, but the form is now broken)

Finally, to make the form work, put this code to run when the user click the submit button, or whenever you want to trigger the form submittion:

```
var sI = $(".passwordInput")[0];
$(sI).attr("id", "password");
$(sI).attr("name", "password");
```

In my case, I used to hav `id="password" name="password"` in the password input, so I put them back before trigger the submition.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue where the input field took either a name or an email. I set autocomplete="off" but Chrome still forced suggestions. Turns out it was because the placeholder text had the words "name" and "email" in it.

For example

```
<input type="text" placeholder="name or email" autocomplete="off" />
```

I got around it by putting a zero width space into the words in the placeholder. No more Chrome autocomplete.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="nam&#8203;e or emai&#8203;l" autocomplete="off" />
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of **autocomplete="off"** use **autocomplete="false"** ;)

from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29582380/75799

Answer (score 5):

In Chrome 48+ use this solution:

1. Put fake fields before real fields:

   ```
   <form autocomplete="off">
     <input name="fake_email"    class="visually-hidden" type="text">
     <input name="fake_password" class="visually-hidden" type="password">

     <input autocomplete="off" name="email"    type="text">
     <input autocomplete="off" name="password" type="password">
   </form>
   ```
2. Hide fake fields:

   ```
   .visually-hidden {
     margin: -1px;
     padding: 0;
     width: 1px;
     height: 1px;
     overflow: hidden;
     clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
     clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
     position: absolute;
   }
   ```
3. You did it!

Also this will work for older versions.

Comment: @yivo Looks like the only diff between urs and og answer is the !important tags, so I added them, still not working. https://www.dropbox.com/s/24yaz6ut7ygkoql/Screen%20Shot%202017-08-29%20at%206.40.53%20AM.png?dl=0

Comment: @MikePurcell You don't have `autocomplete="off"` on the `form` tag. Also try to put fake inputs immediately after `form` tag.

Comment: @Yivo: Tried your suggestions, worked fine for email field, however autofill dropdown still happens for password field. https://www.dropbox.com/s/5pm5hjtx1s7eqt3/Screen%20Shot%202017-08-30%20at%208.03.40%20AM.png?dl=0

Answer (score 5):

I managed to disable autocomple exploiting this rule:

> Fields that are not passwords, but should be obscured, such as credit
> card numbers, may also have a type="password" attribute, but should
> contain the relevant autocomplete attribute, such as "cc-number" or
> "cc-csc".
> https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/create-amazing-password-forms

```
<input id="haxed" type="password" autocomplete="cc-number">
```

However it comes with the great responsibility :)

> Don’t try to fool the browser Password managers (either built into the
> browser, or external) are designed to ease the user experience.
> Inserting fake fields, using incorrect autocomplete attributes or
> taking advantage of the weaknesses of the existing password managers
> simply leads to frustrated users.

Comment: now it shows CC suggestions instead of other form suggestions...

Answer (score 4):

Whilst I agree autocomplete should be a user choice, there are times when Chrome is over-zealous with it (other browsers may be too). For instance, a password field with a different name is still auto-filled with a saved password and the previous field populated with the username. This particularly sucks when the form is a user management form for a web app and you don't want autofill to populate it with your own credentials.

Chrome completely ignores autocomplete="off" now. Whilst the JS hacks may well work, I found a simple way which works at the time of writing:

Set the value of the password field to the control character 8 (`"\x08"` in PHP or `&#8;` in HTML). This stops Chrome auto-filling the field because it has a value, but no actual value is entered because this is the backspace character.

Yes this is still a hack, but it works for me. YMMV.

Comment: I think they've picked up this hack and ignored control characters in the value, so it now evaluates to empty. See the answer by @ice-cream http://stackoverflow.com/a/16130452/752696 for the correct, up-to-date solution.

Comment: Same use case here: Working with user management and having own credentials autofilled. However since it's my own code and I reuse the `form` for creating new and editing existing users simply overriding `input` values via JS removed the auto-complete.

Comment: There are situations where it cannot be a user choice, for example in case of password verfication. In these cases there seems to be no way to do that. The browser now always suggests to use a saved password (even with new-password) which defeats the purpose.

Answer (score 4):

As of Chrome 42, none of the solutions/hacks in this thread (as of `2015-05-21T12:50:23+00:00`) work for disabling autocomplete for an individual field or the entire form.

**EDIT:** I've found that you actually only need to insert one dummy email field into your form (you can hide it with `display: none`) before the other fields to prevent autocompleting. I presume that chrome stores some sort of form signature with each autocompleted field and including another email field corrupts this signature and prevents autocompleting.

```
<form action="/login" method="post">
    <input type="email" name="fake_email" style="display:none" aria-hidden="true">
    <input type="email" name="email">
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

The good news is that since the "form signature" is corrupted by this, none of the fields are autocompleted, so no JS is needed to clear the fake fields before submission.

**Old Answer:**

The only thing I've found to be still viable is to insert two dummy fields of type email and password before the real fields. You can set them to `display: none` to hide them away (it isn't smart enough to ignore those fields):

```
<form action="/login" method="post">
    <input type="email" name="fake_email" style="display:none" aria-hidden="true">
    <input type="password" name="fake_password" style="display:none" aria-hidden="true">
    <input type="email" name="email">
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Unfortunately, the fields must be within your form (otherwise both sets of inputs are autofilled). So, for the fake fields to be truly ignored you'll need some JS to run on form submit to clear them:

```
form.addEventListener('submit', function() {
    form.elements['fake_email'].value = '';
    form.elements['fake_password'].value = '';
});
```

---

Notice from above that clearing the value with Javascript works to override the autocomplete. So if loosing the proper behavior with JS disabled is acceptable, you can simplify all of this with a JS autocomplete "polyfill" for Chrome:

```
(function(document) {

    function polyfillAutocomplete(nodes) {

        for(var i = 0, length = nodes.length; i < length; i++) {

            if(nodes[i].getAttribute('autocomplete') === 'off') {

                nodes[i].value = '';
            }
        }
    }

    setTimeout(function() {

        polyfillAutocomplete(document.getElementsByTagName('input'));
        polyfillAutocomplete(document.getElementsByTagName('textarea'));

    }, 1);

})(window.document);
```

Answer (score 3):

I just updated to **Chrome 49** and [Diogo Cid's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22694173/4120911) doesn't work anymore.

I made a different workaround hiding and removing the fields at run-time after the page is loaded.

Chrome now ignores the original workaround applying the credentials to the first **displayed** `type="password"` field and its previous `type="text"` field, so I have hidden both fields using *CSS* `visibility: hidden;`

```
<!-- HTML -->
<form>
    <!-- Fake fields -->
    <input class="chromeHack-autocomplete">
    <input type="password" class="chromeHack-autocomplete">

    <input type="text" placeholder="e-mail" autocomplete="off" />
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off" />
</form>

<!-- CSS -->
.chromeHack-autocomplete {
    height: 0px !important;
    width: 0px !important;
    opacity: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important; margin: 0 !important;
}

<!--JavaScript (jQuery) -->
jQuery(window).load(function() {
    $(".chromeHack-autocomplete").delay(100).hide(0, function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

I know that it may seem not very elegant but it works.

Answer (score 3):

Chrome keeps changing the way it handles autocomplete on each version, the way I came up was, to make the fields readonly and onclick/focus make it Not readonly. try this jQuery snippet.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
//======fix for autocomplete
$('input, :input').attr('readonly',true);//readonly all inputs on page load, prevent autofilling on pageload

 $('input, :input').on( 'click focus', function(){ //on input click
 $('input, :input').attr('readonly',true);//make other fields readonly
 $( this ).attr('readonly',false);//but make this field Not readonly
 });
//======./fix for autocomplete
});
```

Comment: Thanks, only solution that worked.

jQuery().ready(function($){
 
 // avoid autofill with Chrome 84
 
 $('input').attr('readonly', true);
 $('input').val('');
 
 $('input').on( 'click focus', function(){
  $(this).attr('readonly', false);
 });

});

Comment: Thanks a lot. This solution worked for me with filters input (p:datatable) of primefaces.

Answer (score 3):

**2021 answer:**
Sadly, the only things that work are disgustingly hacky. My solution is to add a dynamically generated random number to the end of the name attribute (E.g. <input name="postcode-22643"...) when generating your front-end markup. This tricks the browser suitably for now.

You'll then need to add something server-side to cleanse the incoming post request. For example, within NodeJS / Express, I've put a middleware in, with a bit of regex to remove the number segment from the received post request. Mine looks like this, but I imagine something pretty similar would be available in other languages:

```
const cleanseAutosuggest = function (req, res, next) {
   for (const key in req.body) {
      if (key.match(/-\d+/)) {
         req.body[key.replace(/-\d+/, "")] = req.body[key];
         delete req.body[key];
      }
   }
   next();
};

app.post("/submit", cleanseAutosuggest, function (req, res, next) {
...
})
```

Answer (score 3):

I have a VERY simple solution to this problem no code required and an acceptable solution.  Chrome often reads the label of the input and does AutoComplete.  You can simply insert an "empty" character into the label.

```
E.g. <label>Surname</labe>

Becomes: <label>Sur&#8205;name</label>
```

‍ is the HTML escape character for "Empty string".

This will still show "Surname" but the Autocomplete wont detect the field and try autocompleting it.

Comment: MARCH 2022 - For me this is the only solution that works now. I have a "country" dropdown which I don't want to autocomplete. I use React Semantic, and has to insert the escape code into my label, and also, wrap it in a <span> like...

`label={{children: <span>Cou&#8205;ntry</span>}}`

Comment: This is the only solution I could get to work. NOTE that the label (surname in this case) does NOT have to be associated with the input control by 'for' and an id. Chrome is smart enough to figure out this by placement on the form just above the input. I wonder how long it will take them to figure this one out and break it again. But do your fellow developers a favor and put a commented version of the text nearby, so that they can search for the string in the html and not headscratch for 10 minutes looking for it.

Answer (score 2):

i found this solution to be the most appropriate:

```
function clearChromeAutocomplete()
{
// not possible, let's try: 
if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') >= 0) 
{
document.getElementById('adminForm').setAttribute('autocomplete', 'off'); 
setTimeout(function () {
        document.getElementById('adminForm').setAttribute('autocomplete', 'on'); 
}, 1500);
}
}
```

It must be loaded after dom ready, or after the form renders.

Answer (score 2):

I solved in another way. You can try this.

```
<input id="passfld" type="text" autocomplete="off" />
<script type="text/javascript">
// Using jQuery
$(function(){                                               
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("input#passfld").attr("type","password");
    },10);
});


// or in pure javascript
 window.onload=function(){                                              
    setTimeout(function(){  
        document.getElementById('passfld').type = 'password';
    },10);
  }   
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

After having tried all solutions, Here is what seems to be working for chrome version:45, with form having password field :

```
 jQuery('document').ready(function(){
        //For disabling Chrome Autocomplete
        jQuery( ":text" ).attr('autocomplete','pre'+Math.random(0,100000000));
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

`autocomplete="off"` works now, so you can just do the following:

```
<input id="firstName2" name="firstName2" autocomplete="off">
```

Tested in the current Chrome 70 as well as in all versions starting from Chrome 62.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AlexandrAbakumov/L0e2u7v4/124/):

- the top `input` has the auto complete working
- **the bottom** `input` has the auto complete **disabled** by adding `autocomplete="off"`

Comment: @AntonKuznetsov Please take a closer look at the JSFiddle's HTML: the bottom `input` has `autocomplete="off"`, whereas the upper one doesn't. So, the auto completer is meant to be disabled for the bottom `input` only, but on your screen shot you're testing auto complete on the upper one. Thus, this still is the proper way of disabling the auto complete for Chrome 70. I'd appreciate if you check it out more thoroughly and upvote this one instead of downvoting.

Comment: This is the correct answer for  Chrome 81 (81.0.4044.138)

Answer (score 2):

For me setting autocomplete="off" in form and inputs worked. But can be flake. Some times it will suggest password or some saved login+password option. But don't come pre-filled.

Chrome Version: 81.0.4044.138

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/farukaf/pen/RwrdmeJ)

```html
<form role="form" method="post" action="#" autocomplete="off">
  <label for="login">Login</label><br/>
  <input type="text" name="login" id="login" autocomplete="off" />
  <br/><br/>
  <label for="password">Password</label><br/>
  <input type="password" name="password" autocomplete="off" />
  <br/><br/>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Others Options:

1. Remove 'form' tag... or changing it from 'div' to 'form' before submitting.
2. With javascript and some contentEditable="true" fields could make your way...

Usually I have to find another work around every few months...

Answer (score 2):

After lot of digging I found that autocomplete dropdown on Chrome(Version 83.0.4103.116) doesn't shows up when we remove name and id attribute on input tag
eg. code as below

```html
<div>
<span>
  Auto complete off works if name and id attribute is not set on input tag 
  <input type="text"/>
</span>
<span>
  Auto complete will work here since id attribute is set
  <input id="name" type="text"/>
</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The only solution that worked and tested successfully on Chrome and Firefox is to wrap the `input` with a `form` that has `autocomplete="off"` as per below:

```html
<form autocomplete="off">
   <input id="xyz" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The hidden input element trick still appears to work (Chrome 43) to prevent autofill, but one thing to keep in mind is that Chrome will attempt to autofill based on the placeholder tag. You need to match the hidden input element's placeholder to that of the input you're trying to disable.

In my case, I had a field with a placeholder text of 'City or Zip' which I was using with Google Place Autocomplete. It appeared that it was attempting to autofill as if it were part of an address form. The trick didn't work until I put the same placeholder on the hidden element as on the real input:

```html
<input style="display:none;" type="text" placeholder="City or Zip" />
<input autocomplete="off" type="text" placeholder="City or Zip" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is fixed! See https://codereview.chromium.org/1473733008

Answer (score 1):

When using a widget like [jQuery UI's Autocomplete](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) make sure to check that it is not adding/changing to autocomplete attribute to off. I found this to be true when using it and will break any work you may have done to override any browser field caching. Make certain that you have a unique name attribute and force a unique autocomplete attribute after the widget initializes. See below for some hints on how that might work for your situation.

```
<?php $autocomplete = 'off_'.time(); ?>
<script>
   $('#email').autocomplete({
      create: function( event, ui ) {
         $(this).attr('autocomplete','<? echo $autocomplete; ?>');
      },
      source: function (request, response) { //your code here },
      focus: function( event, ui ) { //your code here },
      select: function( event, ui ) { //your code here },
   });
</script>
<input type="email" id="email" name="email_<? echo $autocomplete; ?>" autocomplete="<? echo $autocomplete; ?>" />
```

Answer (score 1):

**MAR 2020**

I'm facing this issue and unfortunately non of the solutions worked for me. So I applied the little hack which is working fine.

```
<input autocomplete="off" type="password" name="password" id="password" readonly="readonly">

$('#password').on('click', function (event) {
  $('#password').removeAttr('readonly');
  $('#password').focus();
});

$('#password').on('blur', function (event) {
  $('#password').attr('readonly', 'readonly');
});
```

when you click on password input field it start to show suggestion but when trigger focus on input field than it does not show suggestions so that's how I solved my issue.

I hope it will help someone.

Comment: I found that in 11/21, just adding 

$(document).ready(function(){
$('#password').prop('readonly', false);
});

Worked fine

Answer (score 1):

None of these methods work anymore, chrome ignores all of these attributes, the only solution is to use jquery

use this on input

`<input onclick="$(this).removeAttr('readonly');" onblur="$(this).attr('readonly', true);" readonly />`

Comment: Yep - Chrome disabled support for the autocomplete attribute in 96 (testing on Version 96.0.4664.55). Hopefully this is a mistake...

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the Chrome autocomplete event is triggered on `DOMContentLoaded`, and in the lastest version of Chrome (110.0.5481.178) now ignores `autocomplete="nope"` and `autocomplete="new-password"` or random attribute, so if you don't want to use the readonly trick or other JQuery and Js randomness things you can just set the inputs (email, password and tel mainly) to text and in the `load` event just re-set to the correct type, this should be at least 1ms after the `load` event because if it's done immediately it will be autocompleted by the browser, so just do this trick:

Set the input to `type` to "text" and store the real type on some attribute or class like whis:

```
<input type="text" id="infoEmail" placeholder="something@example.com" data-on-load-type="email">
```

Then, in the window `load` event use the `setTimeout` function and it's done, the input will have the right type and won't be autocomplete

```
window.addEventListener('load', ()=>{
    document.querySelectorAll('input[data-on-load-type]').forEach(trickedInput=>{
        trickedInput.setAttribute('type', trickedInput.getAttribute('data-on-load-type'))
    });
});
```

Edit: just want to add more info about how the autocomplete seems to work.

The autocomplete happens most of the time when are a password and at least other input element in the DOM, the browser will treat everything posssible as a autocompletable, even if theese aren't in a `<form>` tag or has the `autocomplete` atribute to nope or new-password, so if a password input is found and any other autocompletable input such as email, tel or adress thoose will be autocomplete, but not if they have a `display: none;` so the browser will try to fill anyways any other input element visible, even if is not related to a contact or login form, like a input search on a search bar, and if you have a script to display the inputs sometimes they will be autocompleted if an input password is on the DOM, so this is a big problem and browsers should respect when something shouldn't be autocomplete.
So, once the browser knows that there's a input password on the DOM it seems to attach a listenner to autocomplete inputs when they change their display, so i found this solution by setting the type to text, and then changing it to the correct type with a little delay after the load event, it seems to work pretty well, for now.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent autocomplete, just set an empty space as the input value:

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="  ">
```

Comment: This makes no sense... Most of the times you want to use the value attribute and it will only not show autocomplets because nothing starts with a space.

Comment: Can you clarify? Autocomplete is only triggered on empty inputs, what I say is that to prevent it  you can render white spaces instead of empty string.

Comment: no, autocomplete triggering on inputs that has a similar starting characters

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me on Chrome Version 51.0.2704.106.`<input id="user_name" type="text" name="user_name" autocomplete="off" required />`
 and in combination with `<input id="user_password" type="password" name="user_password"  autocomplete="new-password" required />`. My problem was that after implementing `new-password` it would still show a drop-down of usernames on the user_name field.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below concept to implement AutoComplete='false' for chrome as well as other browsers. Take a dummy input type which will be hidden with opacity 0. by default chrome browser have triggered the first one which already hidden.

```
<input style="opacity: 0; position: absolute; z-index: -1;" name="email">
<input type="search" name="email" class="form-control" autocomplete="new-email" id="email">
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried the following, and it appears to do the trick on Chrome 53 - it also disables the "Use password for:" drop down when entering the password field.

Simply set your password input type to `text`, and then add the `onfocus` handler (inline or via jQuery/vanilla JS) to set the type to `password`:

```html
onfocus="this.setAttribute('type','password')"
```

Or even better:

```html
onfocus="if(this.getAttribute('type')==='text') this.setAttribute('type','password')"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this right after form tag:

```
<form>
<div class="div-form">
<input type="text">
<input type="password" >
</div>
```

Add this to your css file:

```
.div-form{
opacity: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'am using Chrome - Version 64.0.3282.140 (Official Build) (64-bit) and used following code along with form name and it works for me.

```
<form name="formNameHere">....</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.formNameHere.reset();
    },500);
</script>
```

Comment: The problem is that the user can still choose to use the saved passwords after the initial clean by just focusing either user/password fields. At least in Chrome, it prompts to use saved credentials. This basically breaks any other attempt to clean / reset fields.

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions worked except for giving it a fake field to autocomplete.  I made a React component to address this issue.

```js
import React from 'react'

// Google Chrome stubbornly refuses to respect the autocomplete="off" HTML attribute so
// we have to give it a "fake" field for it to autocomplete that never gets "used".

const DontBeEvil = () => (
  <div style={{ display: 'none' }}>
    <input type="text" name="username" />
    <input type="password" name="password" />
  </div>
)

export default DontBeEvil
```

Answer (score 0):

I call this the sledgehammer approach, but it seems to work for me where all other approaches I tried have failed:

```
<input autocomplete="off" data-autocomplete-ninja="true" name="fa" id="fa" />
```

Note: the input name and id attributes should not contain anything that would give the browser a hint as to what the data is, or this solution will not work. For instance, I'm using "fa" instead of "FullAddress".

And the following script on page load (this script uses JQuery):

```
$("[data-autocomplete-ninja]").each(function () {
    $(this).focus(function () {
        $(this).data("ninja-name", $(this).attr("name")).attr("name", "");
    }).blur(function () {
        $(this).attr("name", $(this).data("ninja-name"));
    });
});
```

The above solution should prevent the browser from autofilling data gathered from other forms, or from previous submits on the same form.

Basically, I'm removing the name attribute while the input is in focus. As long as you're not doing anything requiring the name attribute while the element is in focus, such as using selectors by element name, this solution should be innocuous.

Answer (score 0):

For this problem I have used this css solution. It is working for me.

```
input{
  text-security:disc !important;
  -webkit-text-security:disc !important;
  -moz-text-security:disc !important;
}
```

Comment: it doesn't help also text-security use case is totally different and un-related to autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue with one of the search field in my form. neither `autocomplete= "false"` nor `autocomplete= "off"` worked for me. turns out when you have aria-label attribute in the `input` element is set to something like `city` or `address` or something similar , chrome overrides all your settings and display the autocomplete anyway

So fix i have done is to remove the `city` part from the aria-label and come up with a different value. and finally autocomplete stopped showing

[image: chrome overrides autocomplete settings]

Answer (score 0):

I have a nearly perfect solution for this issue:
Remove "type=password" from all password input elements,after all of them were loaded into DOM,give a timeout to set the "type=password" back.Chrome will ignore 
the changed type for auto filling.Example:

```
setTimeout(()=>{ele.type="password"},3000)
```

Or change the type by event:

```
ele.oninput=function(){ele.type="password"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found another solution - just mask the characters in your `autocomplete="off"` inputs with `style="-webkit-text-security: disc;"`.
You can also add it to your CSS rules in something like following way:

```css
[autocomplete="off"] {
  -webkit-text-security: disc;
}
```

The main goal is to elminate the `type="password"` or other simillar type attribute from the element.

At least, for the moment of `2021-01-24` this solution works...

Answer (score 0):

Basically we can get rid of the autocomplete from any textbox from chrome, firefox or any kind of browsers. It's simple javascript.

```
window.onload=function(){                                              
        setTimeout(function(){  
            document.getElementById('username').value = '';
            document.getElementById('password').value = '';
        },100);
    }
```

When your window is finish loading, after 100 milliseconds our username and password fields value going to delete.
I think it is the best way to do autocomplete off on all browsers (Specially for chrome).

Answer (score 0):

**2021 September Answer**

As I had to deal with this issue the only stable working solution was to generate a random string for `name` and `autocomplete` attribute in the `<input>` elements each time when the website is rendered.

A simple demo for this using pure JavaScript is below.

Html:

```
<div>
     <h3>Autofill disabled with random string</h3>
     <form id="disable-autofill-form">
       <div>
         <span>First Name</span>
         <input type="text" />
       </div>
       <div>
         <span>Last Name</span>
         <input type="text" />
       </div>
       <div>
         <span>City</span>
         <input type="text" />
       </div>
       <div>
         <span>Street</span>
         <input type="text" />
       </div>
       <div>
         <span>Postal Code</span>
         <input type="text" />
       </div>
     </form>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
const randomString = (Math.random() + 1).toString(36).substring(5);
const disableAutoFillForm = document.getElementById('disable-autofill-form');
const disableAutoFillFormInputs = [
  ...disableAutoFillForm.getElementsByTagName('input'),
];
disableAutoFillFormInputs.forEach((input) => {
  input.setAttribute('autocomplete', randomString);
  input.setAttribute('name', randomString);
});
```

A Stackblitz project to play around with it [can be found here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/autofill-disable-demo?file=index.js).

Answer (score 0):

I just find a trick:

```
<input type="password" id="some_id" name="some_name" value=" " placeholder="Password">

<script>
 $(function)
 {
    $("#some_id").val("");
 }
</script>
```

note that value is blank space. It prevents autompiling in Chrome and input field shows placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem lately and non of the answers worked for me. In my case, as I didn't care for the input field to be nested inside a "form" tag, I fixed chrome autocomplete problem by providing an empty datalist to the input. So now chrome should provide you with autocomplete suggestions from the "datalist" which is empty. Have in mind that this solution does not work if the input is nested in a "form" tag. Surprisingly nothing else worked for me but this trick.

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" list="emptyList" />
<datalist id="emptyList"></datalist>
```

You can learn more about data lists here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist

Considering browser compatibility, it seems to be safe to use.

Answer (score 0):

**2024**

Using Jquery:

```
'use strict';
$(document).ready(function(){
    var inputs = $('input.autocomplete_off');
    inputs.each(function() {
        $(this).attr('readonly');
    });
});

'use strict';
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.autocomplete_off').on('click', function(){
        $(this).removeAttr('readonly')
    })
});
```

How to use?

```
<input class="autocomplete_off"></input>
```

Answer (score -1):

I had to adress this issue on a drupal page with a huge webform. Because I can not edit the html code of every input, I came up with the following generic jQuery solution.

```
<script>

    // Form Autocomplete FIX
    function is_mobile() {
        if( screen.width < 500 || navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i) ) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    jQuery( 'input[autocomplete="off"]' ).each( function() {
        if( is_mobile() ) {
            return;
        }
        jQuery( this ).attr( 'readonly', true );
    } );
    jQuery( 'input[autocomplete="off"]' ).focus( function() {
        if( is_mobile() ) {
            return;
        }
        jQuery( this ).removeAttr( 'readonly' );
        jQuery( this ).focus();
    } );
    jQuery( 'input[autocomplete="off"]' ).blur( function() {
        if( is_mobile() ) {
            return;
        }
        jQuery( this ).attr( 'readonly', true );
    } );

</script>
```

Browser detection from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6622980/1278475).

I guess there is a possibility to optimize this code (I'd love to get some advice), but you'll get the idea from it.

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution that works for me. It doesn't disable autocomplete but allows to customize it. Tested in Chrome 96, Opera 82

```
/* Change Autocomplete styles in Chrome*/
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
textarea:-webkit-autofill,
textarea:-webkit-autofill:hover,
textarea:-webkit-autofill:focus,
select:-webkit-autofill,
select:-webkit-autofill:hover,
select:-webkit-autofill:focus {
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px transparent inset;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I've came up with the following solution that queries all fields with the attribute `autocomple="off"` then set it's value to a single space then set a timer for around 200ms and set the value back to an empty string.

Example:

```
// hack to prevent auto fill on chrome
var noFill = document.querySelectorAll("input[autocomplete=off]");

noFill.forEach(function(el) {
    el.setAttribute("value", " ");
    setTimeout(function() {
        el.setAttribute("value", "");
    }, 200);
});
```

I choose 200ms for the timer because after some experimentation 200ms seems to be the amount of time it takes on my computer for chrome to give up on trying to autocomplete the fields. I'm welcome to hear what other times seem to work better for other people.

Comment: The timing varies too much for me for this to be useful - I've tried similar and it varies on the same page in the same browser.