# Jquery disable autocomplete in input

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I have this code:

The html:

```
<input id="register_username" type="text">
<input id="register_password" type="text">
<input id="register_repeatpassword" type="text">
<input id="register_email" type="text">
```

The Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#register_username').attr('autocomplete','off');
    $('#register_password').attr('autocomplete','off');
    $('#register_repeatpassword').attr('autocomplete','off');
    $('#register_email').attr('autocomplete','off');
    });
```

I want to disable the autocomplete feature offred by some browsers and acctually make the user type the entire field but the code is not working the dropdown menu still appear and the user still able to choose stuff the typed before. I also tried to user `autocomplete="off"` but nothing happened. What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: [works on my machine](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/03/the-works-on-my-machine-certification-program.html)(tm)

Comment: For me the autocomplete="off" is being ignored on Chrome (v 41.0.2272.89), first I thought it was because I was changing the attribute via jquery after the page was loaded, but even inserting `autocomplete="off"` directly on the `input` did not solve the issue. This other [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374442/chrome-browser-ignoring-autocomplete-off) might be related to the issue.

Answer (score 34):

Just add:

```
autocomplete="off"
```

as attributes to the `INPUT` elements, f.ex:

```
<input autocomplete="off" id="register_username" type="text" name="username">
```

Comment: or the `<form>` node as well. (btw I believe the root problem is that it doesn't appear to work when applied post-load by jQuery since OP is adding this very attribute).

Comment: @MaxPain what browser? Can you post a fiddle?

Answer (score 22):

The **jQuery** version:

```
$("#register_username").attr("autocomplete", "off");
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: It's the same as all the other answers, except that it uses jQuery, which is all it claims to do.

Comment: The OP asked what was wrong with their own code, not for alternate methods of doing it. Some of the other answers are not answering the OP's question either, but the reviewer queue doesn't present all answers to be reviewed at once.

Comment: Anyway, that was three years ago...Today I wouldn't bother commenting on something like this since it's still helpful to people. :)

Answer (score 11):

in case someone comes here looking for how to turn off their jquery autocomplete:

```
$("#elementId").autocomplete({
  disabled: true
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion.  Trying $("#id").attr("autcomplete", "off") or with false, or some other value didn't work but your solution did.

Comment: Awesome be sure to give it a like!

Answer (score 6):

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jtFec/) out

```
 document.getElementById("register_username").autocomplete="off"
```

Answer (score 5):

Now a days you need change "off" to another random string like "nope":

**Jquery:**

```
$("#register_username").attr("autocomplete", "nope");
```

**HTML:**

```
<input id="register_username" type="text" autocomplete="nope">
```

Answer (score 4):

Though I agree, `autocomplete="off"` should be widely supported and is the end solution, it not working may be a result of the [HTML5 spec on the autocomplete attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-autocomplete-attribute):

> The autocompletion mechanism must be implemented by the user agent acting as if the user had modified the element's value, and **must be done at a time where the element is mutable** (e.g. just after the element has been inserted into the document, or when the user agent stops parsing).

That, to me, implies it should be an 'original' attribute of the element, and cannot be added post-render. And since most browsers are implementing the new spec<sup>1</sup>, chances are if they allowed it with javascript before they've probably corrected the implementation based on the above spec.

If you haven't already, try adding the attribute directly to the controls instead of relying on jQuery doing so on [presumably] document ready.

<sup>1</sup> *I use spec losely here since HTML5 isn't a standard, but a lot of browsers are implementing some of the more concrete features. Since `autocomplete` has been around since IE5, it's probably one of those ones you can consider a safe implementation.*

Comment: I tried doing this :`<input id="register_username" type="text" name="username" autocomplete="off">` and still have the same problem.

Comment: @MaxPain: By any changes, if you go to `about:config` is [Wallet.crypto.autocompleteoverride](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Wallet.crypto.autocompleteoverride) set?

Comment: I am not sure what that is. I guess no.

Comment: @MaxPain: Plainly put, there are add-ins to FF that can force it to remember passwords despite preferences set by the webmaster (e.g. setting `autocomplete="off"`). I was just checking to make sure that wasn't the case.

Answer (score 2):

```
<form id='myForm'>
    <input id="register_username" type="text">
    <input id="register_password" type="text">
    <input id="register_repeatpassword" type="text">
    <input id="register_email" type="text">
</form>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myForm').on( 'focus', ':input', function(){
        $(this).attr( 'autocomplete', 'off' );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Working as of April 23rd 2019.

If you want to disable Chrome's autofill on everything on your page, especially if you don't use forms but rather serialized jquery selectors to submit your data.

Doing it at runtime had the best results for me, and Chrome will autofill on runtime anyways, so it's a justifiable solution to counter Chrome's behavior.

Simply add this at the bottom of your code and Chrome won't try to force auto-fill things:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("input").attr("autocomplete", "new-password");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Not working: Chrome 75.0.3770.142. It only works if you put the autocomplete='off' attribute directly on the input element. Every manipulation via js later on is simply ignored.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still struggling with this issue, this combination of solutions is the ONLY thing that worked for me.
Based on this script:
https://github.com/terrylinooo/jquery.disableAutoFill

```
<form id="myForm">...</form>
```

Put these in the footer of your page:

```
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/disableautofill/src/jquery.disableAutoFill.min.js"></script> 
    
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("input").attr("autocomplete", "new-password");
            $('#myForm').disableAutoFill();
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, I do this in a layout page, or a bit of HTML that will be present on every page of the website.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        //when the page is done loading, disable autocomplete on all inputs[text]
        $('input[type="text"]').attr('autocomplete', 'off');

        //do the same when a bootstrap modal dialog is opened
        $(window).on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
            $('input[type="text"]').attr('autocomplete', 'off');
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

in case someone still stcuk, i tried all the above methods and they didnt work but setting autocomplete to none on the input itself worked for me.

`autocomplete="none"`