# How to remove input suggestions in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I want to remove input suggestions in HTML. *The solution can be JavaScript!* I do not know the syntax. To more comprehension of the problem, take a look in the following image:

[image: Remove input suggestions in HTML.]

I've already searched about this question and what I found was `autocomplete="off"`, but I think it was not enough yet, because the problem wasn't resolved.

The code:

```
<input name="productQuantity" maxlength="2" type="text" autocomplete="off" />
```

Comment: Could you post your code? `autocomplete="off"` should be working fine...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2530/753237

Comment: @ic3b3rg As I said: `autocomplete` isn't enough.

Comment: Take another look at that question... there are other solutions there.

Comment: did you try autocomplete=off in the form tag?

Comment: @suspectus Yes, I did.

Comment: In which browser did you found this issue? Wasn't it Chrome? May be this question may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374442/chrome-browser-ignoring-autocomplete-off?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most common trick to remove it is to put the random "name" of field for example "firstname-randomstringhere" and then substract this random string in php.

You should include in your question what have you tried by the way.

This random string may be also generated once and be stored in `$_SESSION`.

Comment: I just have tried `autocomplete="off"`. I don't said before, but I'm using C#.Net. I can't believe that server-side may be compromising, but your suggestion about the session is valid — because I'm using it.

Comment: Let me ask, Robert. Should I use a random and safe name to my input or just different of the session name is enough?

Comment: it's all about the random name within one session of use. It doesn't matter if you use session for it or you don't. Using session has one adventage - the random string is generated once therefore function is called once.

Comment: Oh, got it! Thank you about the explanation. Now is with me.