# How to avoid password being auto-filled

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, flask, passwords

I'm developing an app in Flask using Bootstrap 3 and WTF Forms. In the profile page, the user can change their name, password, etc.

But when I log in and I ask Firefox to remember my password, the new password field is already filled in on the profile page. Simply adding `value=' '` to my form field does not clear the password field of the form.

How do I go about clearing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add a [`autocomplete="off"`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag) to your render call for your password field:

```
{{ form.password(autocomplete="off") }}
```

Alternately, if you are rendering the form using a macro that just loops over each field in the form, you can use a custom widget:

```
from wtforms.widgets import Input

class PasswordWidget(Input):
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if "autocomplete" not in kwargs:
            kwargs["autocomplete"] = "off"
        return super(InputWidget, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
```

and then in that particular form you can set the widget explicitly:

```
class UpdateForm(SomeBaseForm):
    password = StringField("Password", widget=PasswordWidget())
```

Comment: [Recent versions of Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374442/chrome-browser-ignoring-autocomplete-off) have made this much harder - [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374442/chrome-browser-ignoring-autocomplete-off) provides some solutions worth considering.

Comment: Is there any workaround here, if the user has set Firefox to remember the email / password even though I have set the autocomplete="off"?