# ng-form and autocomplete="off"

Tags: html, angularjs

I have an angular form like this

```
<ng-form name="AddTaskForm" autocomplete="off">
   ......
</ng-form>
```

However when I begin entering data, chrome is still prompting me with previously entered values.

How can I prevent chrome (and all browsers) from showing any drop down on my input with previously entered values?

I did some search and found that people were writing custom directives, but not sure if this is really required.

[image]

Answer (score 24):

Despite `autocomplete` being a pretty well defined [part of the HTML5 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html), Chrome has flip-flopped on how they use the `autocomplete` property. [Originally honoring `autocomplete="off"` (2013)](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=252609), they then decided that developers must be using it wrong and the browser should just ignore it.

> This doesn't mean there aren't very valid cases where you don't want the browser autofilling data (e.g. on CRM systems), but by and large, we see those as the minority cases. And as a result, we started ignoring autocomplete=off for Chrome Autofill data.

(Source: [Chromium bug from 2015 marked as WontFix](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=468153))

According to the [Priority of Constituencies](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-design-principles/):

> In case of conflict, consider users over authors over implementors over specifiers over theoretical purity. In other words costs or difficulties to the user should be given more weight than costs to authors; which in turn should be given more weight than costs to implementors...

...Which leaves us developers in the unfortunate spot of finding a work-around. [This article from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion) outlines the current state well, and offers this solution of setting `autocomplete` to `new-password`:

> If an author would like to prevent the autofilling of password fields in user management pages where a user can specify a new password for someone other than themself, autocomplete="new-password" should be specified, though support for this has not been implemented in all browsers yet.

I'm not sure how long this will remain valid, but for now (tested in Chrome 53 in September 2016) this is the easiest solution:

```
<input type="password" name="someName" autocomplete="new-password" />
```

**Edit: Note:** This has the side-effect of asking the user to save the password, possibly overwriting an existing password. So while it does "prevent the autofilling of password fields" it does not remove the element from the autocomplete mess altogether.

**Edit: Updated Info:** Newer versions of Chrome once again respect the `autocomplete=off` attribute, [as Alexander Abakumov pointed out in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52082636/589259). He had it working for Chrome 68, works on Chrome 70 for me.

Answer (score 6):

`autocomplete="off"` works now. Tested in the current Chrome 70.0.3538.110.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/AlexandrAbakumov/L0e2u7v4/144/).

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I'm in Chrome version 70 for Mac and this solution works.

Comment: @DavidKmenta: It works with the same Chrome version on Windows 10. Also, BrendanGoggin commented it's working on Chrome 70 for Mac. I highly doubt something changed around it. Try to test your web app on Chrome for Win and ping back a result, please.

Comment: @AlexanderAbakumov unfortunately I'm not the only one having this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53179114/unexpected-chrome-autofill-behaviour-disable-chrome-autofill ... it seems like there's some unknown logic behind this that only the Chrome team knows  

Comment: @DavidKmenta: One of the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53193537/3345644) there says: `As of recent Chrome (definitely version 70) autocomplete="off" is now respected, as long as your inputs do not look like user profile, address or credit card data.` I personally haven't experienced a situation when `autocomplete="off"` wouldn't work. If you could change my demo to demonstrate one of those situations, it would be very helpful.

Comment: autocomplete="nope" works well in chrome. Refer the reason here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion#Disabling_autocompletion

Comment: @kanagarajpalanisamy The `autocomplete="nope"` approach is not a good idea. It's not cross-browser (your very link says: `this does not work in Firefox; it completely disregards the invalid value and reverts to default autocompletion behavior.`. Also, if it works in the current Chrome, it could easily be changed in the next release since this behavior goes against the standard. Why don't you use `autocomplete="off"`?

Answer (score 1):

It looks Chrome ignores the `autocomplete` property for individual `inputs`; the old work around was to add `autocomplete=off` on the entire form like you have done (which is a pretty incomplete solution as it will then add this functionality to all inputs contained in the form, which may not be desired).

Anyway, from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374442/chrome-browser-ignoring-autocomplete-off) it looks like that work around is no longer available, so it looks like you may need a directive. I know this may not be what you're looking for, but I think it's your only option for chrome.

```
myApp.directive('autocomplete', function() {

    return {    

        restrict: 'A',
        link: function( $scope, el, attr ) {

            el.bind('change', function(e) {

                e.preventDefault();

            }
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: Hmm, did you add `noautocomplete` or `autocomplete`? It's got to be the name of the directive.