# Google Chrome really ignores autocomplete tag?

Tags: google-chrome, autocomplete

I wanted to disable chrome's autofill in one of my forms. I put the code shown in the second answer of this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill)

Actually, after putting this code, it only partially fixed my problem. The form was not autofilled after a page refresh. But If I type something on the textfield, say username, the autofill was there showing the list of usernames. What I did was added `autocomplete = off` for username textfield, problem solved. I was happy. But hold on a second, everyone said that newer versions of chrome completely ignores autocomplete tag. If that so, how then my problem solved when I added `autocomplete = off` for the username textfield. I am really confused. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374442/chrome-browser-ignoring-autocomplete-off/22957859#22957859