# Yii: disable autofill of username and password fields on chrome

Tags: php, html, google-chrome

how can i disable autofill fields in Yii. It automatically loads saved username and password of the logged in user.

```
<?php echo $form->textField($model,'username',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>100, 'class'=> 'form-control input-inline input-medium', 'autocomplete'=>"off")); ?>
<?php echo $form->passwordField($model,'password',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>255, 'class'=> 'form-control input-inline input-medium', 'autocomplete'=>"off")); ?>
```

**NOTE:**
property autocomplete='off' does not work on chrome. It is working on FF.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chrome Browser Ignoring AutoComplete=Off](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374442/chrome-browser-ignoring-autocomplete-off)

Comment: not a duplicate, this asks how to do it in Yii

Answer (score 3):

Try this.  It works in YII 2.0 for all fields.

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'form-name', 'options' => ['autocomplete' => 'off'],]); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

May be this one help:)

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-4">
    <?php echo $form->field($model, 'email',['inputOptions' => [
'autocomplete' => 'off']])?>
 </div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <?php echo $form->field($model, 'password',['inputOptions' => [
'autocomplete' => 'off']])->passwordInput() ?>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice I add directly in the `ActiveForm:begin(['fieldConfig' => ['inputOptions' => ['autocomplete' => 'off']]]);` to apply it to the whole form

Answer (score 2):

I think you can add style class or attributes for textInput like this:

```
$form->field($model, 'plate_number')->textInput(['autocomplete' =>'off']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Browser have decided to override autocomplete off for Login form (username & passwords). That could be in play here.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=956906

http://www.theregister.co.uk/2014/04/09/chrome_makes_new_password_grab_in_version_34/

Try the tricks given in this answer

[Chrome Browser Ignoring AutoComplete=Off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374442/chrome-browser-ignoring-autocomplete-off)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Chrome now ignores autocomplete="off" unless it is on the  tag.  Hope this Helps

Answer (score 0):

```
<?=
 $form->field($form_model, 'password',)
      ->textInput(['autocomplete' => 'off','placeholder'=>'Password'])
?>
```

just use `->textInput(['autocomplete' => 'off'])` in front of field

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'password_change')->passwordInput(['maxlength' => true, 'autocomplete' => 'new-password'])->label(App::t('Current password')) ?>
```