# Autocomplete offf in email and password field in yii2 using ActiveForm

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mysql, yii2

I have used Activeform for the form in yii2 and i have used email and password Input for email and passsword. But i have login for email and passwrod with remember me than email and password field on my form autocomplete by that.
That code is below:

So please help to remove autocomplete using yii2.
This is picture whats happen in that:

I have used following link for solutions but not proper work for me:
[Yii: disable autofill of username and password fields on chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27741675/yii-disable-autofill-of-username-and-password-fields-on-chrome)

```
<div class="col-md-12 mb-0">
<?=$form->field($model, 'coupon_code', ['inputOptions' => ['autocomplete' => 'off'],'template' => ''
. '<div class="input-group mb-3 coupon_parent_div">'
. '{input}'
. '<div class="input-group-append">'
. '<button type="button" id="coupon_btn" class="btn btn-md btn-secondary" onclick="cart_refresh();">Apply</button>'
. '</div>'
. '</div>'
. '{error}'])
->textInput(['class' => 'form-control my_input_border', 'maxlength' => true, 'placeholder' => $model->getAttributeLabel('coupon_code')])?>
</div>
<div class="form-row">
<div class="col-md-3 mb-0">
<?= $form->field($model, 'cc_cvv')->passwordInput(['class' => 'form-control my_input_border', 'maxlength' => 5, 'placeholder' => 'CVV', 'autocomplete' => 'off'])->label(false) ?>
</div>
</div>
<div class="card credit_card_custom_css">
<div class="card-body">
<div class="form-row">
<div class="col-md-7 mb-0">
<?= $form->field($model, 'cc_name',['inputOptions' => ['autocomplete' => 'off']])->textInput(['class' => 'form-control my_input_border marginBottom15', 'maxlength' => true, 'placeholder' => $model->getAttributeLabel('cc_name')])->label(false) ?>
</div>
<div class="col-md-5 mb-0">
<?= $form->field($model, 'cc_number',['inputOptions' => ['autocomplete' => 'new-password']])->textInput(['class' => 'form-control my_input_border marginBottom15', 'maxlength' => true, 'placeholder' => $model->getAttributeLabel('cc_number')])->label(false) ?>
</div>

</div>
<div class="form-row">
<div class="col-md-3 mb-0">
<?= $form->field($model, 'cc_cvv',['inputOptions' => ['autocomplete' => 'new-password']])->passwordInput(['class' => 'form-control my_input_border marginBottom15', 'maxlength' => 5, 'placeholder' => $model->getAttributeLabel('cc_cvv')])->label(false) ?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

This is picture for what happen for me:
[image]

Please help me solve that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modern browser will ignore `Autocomplete="off"` on login fields.

> If a site sets autocomplete="off" for username and password 
>   fields, then the browser will still offer to remember this login, and
>   if the user agrees, the browser will autofill those fields the next
>   time the user visits the page.

See [The autocomplete attribute and login fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion#The_autocomplete_attribute_and_login_fields)