# Ignoring autocomplete='off' in chrome browser

Tags: javascript, html

once user choosing the auto filling option in chrome browser it will auto automatically change the value of this select box according the some deflate values in chrome browser so how can i stop this issue.

I have fond some solutions while i'm googling so it also not working. is there any other solution

1st option is put autocomplete="off" 
 2nd option is creating fake select box and put style="display: none;"

```
<form:select path="quote.toLocation[${varstat.index}]" multiple="false" cssClass="select_typ1 bigselect drpView_ti" cssErrorClass="errorInput select_typ1 bigselect" onchange="removeError(this);" cssStyle="margin-top: 0px;float: left;" autocomplete="off">
                            <form:option value="">Please select destination</form:option>
                            <form:options items="${countryList}" itemLabel="displayName" 
                                itemValue="code" cssClass="countrySelectClass" />
                        </form:select>
```

Comment: You appear to have forgotten to add your code?

Comment: Is your page HTML5? Or smth else?

Comment: @zozo maybe this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374442/chrome-browser-ignoring-autocomplete-off ?

Comment: i use  autocomplete='off' within select tag also but it is not working is there any other solution to stop auto filling option in chrome browser