# jquery ui-autocomplete and google chrome autocomplete

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, google-chrome

[image]

I am using jquery ui-autocomplete on a zip code form field to suggest zip codes. I have autocomplete off on the form field and the form itself. If i have my address saved in google chrome and i start typing in the zip code box google chrome auto suggests my saved zip code and their suggesting box is ABOVE the jquery ui autocomplete box. any way to either force google chrome to respect the autocomplete off or move the jquery ui box above the chrome autocomplete box?

```
 <form id="bizjoinOneForm" action="#" onSubmit="register(); return false;" autocomplete="off">
  <input type="text" id="bizjoinZipCode" placeholder="Zip Code" onChange="checkZip();" autocomplete="off">
 </form>
```

Comment: Same issue here. Where you able to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22694173/1479535

You can try adding

```
<input style="display:none">
<input type="password" style="display:none">
```

at the start of your `<form>`

Answer (score 0):

Just for anyone that might be looking for this solution,
you can add a autocomplete="off" in the open form tag

```
<form ... autocomplete="off" >
```

Answer (score 0):

`<input autocomplete="off" />`

...works until:

[Chrome does not respect autocomplete="off"](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=468153#c164)

if you are hitting that use:

`<input autocomplete="anything_but_off"/>`