# Chrome auto complete data overlaying datepicker

Tags: datepicker, autofill

I'm having issues with Chrome auto-complete data overlaying on Jquery Datepicker and haven't had any luck with `autocomplete='off'` so wondered if anyone had any luck with a non script solution?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The following question is similar : [jquery ui-autocomplete and google chrome autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29286244/jquery-ui-autocomplete-and-google-chrome-autocomplete)

I worked around the problem by adding the **autocomplete** attribute for the **input** node

```
<input autocomplete="off"
```

It works for Chrome Version 107.0.5304.62