# Autocomplete off vs false?

Tags: html, google-chrome, autocomplete, w3c

Recently I have come across an issue where I wanted to disable auto-complete in all browsers.

Chrome has a new feature in settings where you can add a card number. And the requirement was to also disable that.

What worked in all browsers was to do this `autocomplete=false` at form level.

But this is not compliant with w3 rules, where they enforce to have `autocomplete=off|on`.

**Can someone please explain to me why `false` works in all browsers?**

even ie8, all firefox, safari etc., but it is not compliant.

Comment: I was able to find the solution from another post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38961567/2038779

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disabling Chrome Autofill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Autocomplete Off is completely Ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29432665/autocomplete-off-is-completely-ignored) and [Autocomplete populating wrong field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34443628/autofill-populating-wrong-fields)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You are right. Setting the autocomplete attribute to "off" does not disable Chrome autofill in more recent versions of Chrome.

However, you can set autocomplete to anything besides "on" or "off" ("false", "true", "nofill") and it will disable Chrome autofill.

This behavior is probably because the autocomplete attribute expects either an "on" or "off" value and doesn't do anything if you give it something else. So if you give it something other than those values, autofill falls apart/doesn't do anything.

<s>With the current version of Chrome it has been found that setting the autocomplete attribute to "off" actually works now.</s>

Also, I have found that this only works if you set the autocomplete attribute in each `<input>` tag of the form.

There has been a response to this ambiguity in the Chromium bug listings [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=468153#c164).

Disclaimer: This was found to be true in Chrome version 47.0.2526.106 (64-bit)

Comment: @pauel I'm having a hard time replicating behavior where this solution doesn't work. Could you post an example where this isn't working?

Comment: I am finding that "false" does not work, but "off" does. I'm using Chrome 46.0.2490.71

Comment: @seesharper I can confirm the behavior you are talking about. Must have been fixed in more recent versions of chrome I guess. Interesting

Comment: False still works, not "off". Version 47.0.2526.106 m

Comment: @OlivierPons interesting. I see this behavior as well. I will update my answer once again

Comment: For all newcomers: I can confirm that autocomplete="off" on "form" in Chrome now works correctly (v56).

Comment: No autocomplete attribute values seems to work for Chrome 62. Chrome 62 insists on auto-completing inputs no despite what I set the autocomplete attribute to.

Comment: No value for the autocomplete attribute appears to work for Chrome 62. Chrome 62 insists on auto-completing an input despite the autocomplete value.

Comment: To disable it for all input tags, i used:
jQuery("input").attr("autocomplete", Math.random());

Answer (score 22):

After Chrome version 72.XX:

Chrome ignores `autocomplete="off"` `autocomplete="no-fill"` or `autocomplete="randomText"` both on field and form level.

The only option I found is to follow a work-around by tricking Chrome to populate the autofill on a dummy Textbox and password and then hide them from the user view.

Remember the old method with `style="display: hidden"` or `style="visibility: hidden"` is also ignored.

FIX:

So create a `DIV` with `height: 0px;overflow:hidden` which will still render the HTML elements but hide them from User's view.

Sample Code:

```
<div style="overflow: hidden; height: 0px;background: transparent;" data-description="dummyPanel for Chrome auto-fill issue">
        <input type="text" style="height:0;background: transparent; color: transparent;border: none;" data-description="dummyUsername"></input>
        <input type="password" style="height:0;background: transparent; color: transparent;border: none;" data-description="dummyPassword"></input>
</div>
```

Just add the above div within the HTML Form and it should work!

Comment: Why do the Chrome engineers seem to think they know better than the people actually building the sites on the web and keep finding ways to re-enable autocomplete? The arrogance is stunning.

Comment: @JAC not always. Just tested a form in Chrome 74, then updated to Chrome 75, and the autofill does appear for me in them both, whatever is in the autofill attribute. Under some conditions, including personalized, Chrome offers to autofill, completely covering my cool datepicker calendar in the process. Haven't got a test case.

Comment: Chrome is becoming almost as annoying as IE.

Comment: https://www.codementor.io/@leonardofaria/disabling-autofill-in-chrome-zec47xcui

Comment: The Sample Code has a typo: the outer <div> needs "overflow: hidden" -- "overflow: none" is not a thing.

Comment: what a hack sir ji

Answer (score 17):

Use ***autocomplete="my-field-name"*** instead of *autocomplete="off"*. Be careful what you call it, since some values are still recognized like autocomplete="country". I also found that using the placeholder attribute helped in some tricky scenarios.

**Example:**
    *`<input type="text" name="field1" autocomplete="my-field-name1" placeholder="Enter your name">`*

Chrome recently stopped using *autocomplete="off"* because they thought it was overused by developers who didn't put much thought into whether or not the form should autocomplete. Thus they took out the old method and made us use a new one to ensure we really don't want it to autocomplete.

Comment: Do you have any links to any citations/articles/discussions about this?

Comment: Never mind, found it: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=468153#c164

Answer (score 7):

```
$("#selector").attr("autocomplete", "randomString");
```

This has worked reliably everytime for me.

**Note : I have invoked this LOC on modal show event.**

Comment: are you generating a random string for ever form view?

Comment: @Raghav  can you please create jsfiddle and tell us what version are you working on?

Comment: @Raghav You seem to be right. Here is jsfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/doeL0t1g/14/

Comment: https://www.codementor.io/@leonardofaria/disabling-autofill-in-chrome-zec47xcui

Comment: This one worked for me even without jQuery, simply adding the attribute in the html text input field.

Answer (score 7):

If anyones reading this and is having difficulty disabling autocomplete on username and password fields for new users, I found setting autocomplete="new-password" works in Chrome 77. It also prevented the username field from auto completing.

Ref: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#autofill

Comment: Agree autocomplete="new-password" is by far the simplest workaround to this Chrome issue

Answer (score 6):

Auto complete value other that off and false works.

`autoComplete="nope"`
`autoComplete="foo"`
`autoComplete="boo"`
`autoComplete="anythingGoesHere"`

Tested on chrome 76 and react 16.9.0

Comment: https://www.codementor.io/@leonardofaria/disabling-autofill-in-chrome-zec47xcui

Comment: @JoyAcharya This solved my problem with Chrome's autofill feature. This should be the recommended solution.

Answer (score 3):

It's 2020 and if someone is still struggling with it as I did. The only solution that worked for me is as follows, setting autocomplete to any random string disables the autocomplete but it works only if its done after the page load. If that random string is kept as default value then chrome annoyingly sets it back to off. So what worked for me is (I'm using jquery) on document ready event, I added the following,

```
window.setTimeout(function () {
        $('your-selector').attr('autocomplete', 'google-stop-doing-this');
}, 1000);
```

Without the timeout, Chrome still somehow resets its back to off.

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:
.

```html
<input type="text" autocomplete="__away">
```

Comment: This even works for React Native's TextInput with react-native-web. autoComplete="__away"

Answer (score 2):

**autocomplete="none"** perfectly works for angularjs and angular 7

Comment: Not anymore. Chrome 75

Comment: try autocomplete="chrome-off" it worked for me in chrome v84

Comment: @EduardVoid Tried it with chrome 84, it did not work

Answer (score 2):

if there any "password type input" in your form you can try this;

```
<input type="password" ..... autocomplete="new-password" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this over input tag:

```
readonly onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');
```

Example:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="false" readonly onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');">
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the autocomplete attribute to true|false or on|off both does not work in all the conditions. Even when you try with to placeholder also it wont work.

I tried to use autocomplete="no" for avoiding the chrome autofill plugin.

This autocomplete="no" should be written inside a input line, for example

Answer (score 0):

Although it might not be the most elegant solution, this worked for me:

JQuery version:

```
$("input:-internal-autofill-selected").val('');
```

VanillaJS version:

```
document.querySelectorAll("input:-internal-autofill-selected").forEach(function(item){item.value = '';})
```

When Chrome autofills an input field, the fields gets an internal pseudo element `-internal-autofill-selected` (which also gives the input the light blue background). We can use this pseudo element as selector in order to undo the Chrome autocomplete/autofill.

Please note that you may (depends on your implementation) need to wrap your code in a timeout as Chrome autofills after the DOM is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Not perfect but working solution using jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome") != -1) {
      $("#selector").attr("autocomplete", "nope"); // to disable auto complete on chrome
   }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
autocomplete="one-time-code"
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still looking for an answer in 2023, try this one as it worked for me. I added a hidden input with `autocomplete=false`

```
<input autocomplete="false" name="hidden" type="text" style="display:none;">
```

Answer (score -5):

As an addition to @camiblanch answer

Adding `autocomplete="off"` [is not gonna cut it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374442/chrome-browser-ignoring-autocomplete-off)
Change input type attribute to `type="search"`.
Google doesn't apply auto-fill to inputs with a type of search.

Comment: You should not use search for not search.

Comment: You cannot use search fields as a substitution for text fields. They even look different on Safari. They look like search fields with rounded corners and reset button.

Comment: You only make your life harder because maybe tomorrow search field will look like a dragon because of new OS update. I use `$(':input', this.$formElement).attr('autocomplete', 'off');` for critical forms. Works in Chrome.

Comment: @Andy have you tried `$(':input', this.$formElement).attr('autocomplete', 'off');` ?

Comment: Yep. Works for me on Chrome on OSX Version 46.0.2490.80 (64-bit). Tried with it off and on. Can see autocomplete completely gone when I set `autocomplete` prop directly on input fields. This didn't work on FORM element though, that's why I had to apply it to all fields.

Comment: @Andy I am very pleased that it does for you, this answer is for those to whom it doesn't.

Comment: Very weak. You are in denial.

Comment: @Andy Ofc I am, https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=468153 so is everyone else (but you). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374442/chrome-browser-ignoring-autocomplete-off

Comment: Stop playing dumb, did you try using the solution that I gave you?

Comment: @Andy Do you really need confirmation that it does not work? Fine, your solution does not work (for everyone, but you ofc).

Comment: I tested it yesterday and it works. I don't understand the reference to everyone. Stay down voted bro, cheer up there

Comment: Neither Jquery's attr autocomplete off or autocomplete=off is working for me in chrome (Version 46.0.2490.80 m (64-bit)). False is working but seems to be overridden by visual studio... This works for me.

Comment: @highmaintenance Confirmed in an upcoming Chrome update, search inputs will be dragons.

Comment: @wesley-murch do you have a link? I will grab some popcorn 