# Autocomplete doesn't turn off

Tags: html, google-chrome, autocomplete

I am trying to turn autocomplete off in my page when users use Google Chrome, but no success. I have looked for information how to solve this and some answers said that you should put autocomplete="off" in form rather than input or to put fake inputs and hide them because Chrome autocompletes only first password input.

Those answers were 2-4 years old an none of them seems to work today. So is there a way to shut autocomplete off in Google Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

The autocomplete attribute to "off" does not disable default Chrome autofill in more recent versions of Chrome. You can set autocomplete to anything besides "on" or "off" ("false", "true", "nofill") and it will disable Chrome autofill.

This solution worked for me, but it depends on the current Chrome, can be different.

Source: [Autocomplete off vs false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30053167/autocomplete-off-vs-false)

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me, but maybe it is possible to delete input values using jQuery as soon as page is loaded?

Comment: Yes, that can be a solution, but it's not so user-friendly. I think it's should be done just with default autofill. You cannot win this fight with all of the browsers with specific user's setting.