# why does my User registration form have some fields pre filled when it actuall suppose to be blank.

Tags: php

I built a simple user registration form using Xtml, php Myadmin.i expect all the field to blank prior to inputing data.But each time i refresh the user registration page some field on the form will be pre filled. . What should i do so that form field should be blank prior to inputing data?

Comment: It may be your browser autofilling forms?

Comment: This was all about symfony? Huh... ok. Nevermind!

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `autocomplete` tag like this

```
<input type="text" name="bar" autocomplete="off" />
```

To turn this browser behaviour off. Be aware that this does not work completely at some Firefox versions.

Comment: Setting to 'false' is more widespread support. (or some random string other than 'off').

Comment: @IncredibleHat that is not what the documentation says.

Comment: Unsure the downvote, but more info is found here too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30081850/2960971

Comment: @IncredibleHat thanks, and indeed.. people like to downvote apparently..