# I have set autocomplete off in input field of html form.It perfectly works in Firefox and safari but is not working in chrome

Tags: php, html, css

I have set autocomplete off in input field of html form. It  perfectly works in Firefox and safari but  is not working in google chrome.

This is my basic Form.

```
<form  action="" autocomplete="off" id="form2" method="post" class="registerDiv">
    <input type="email" name="cust_username_email"  id="cust_username_email" placeholder="E Mail ID* (User Name)" value="" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" />
    <input type="password" name="cust_Pass" id="cust_Pass" required  placeholder="Password* " value="" autocomplete="off" class="form-control"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow :) could you show us your code? We can't necessarily help you without seeing what you've done so far.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Autocomplete off vs false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30053167/autocomplete-off-vs-false)

Comment: Try setting `autocomplete="off"` on your `<form>` element too.

Comment: Go through this link may be its helpful https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion

Comment: hii @DKyleo i have edited my post with a basic form. its working in firefox and safari but is not working in crome

Comment: @kerbholz i already did that but its not working in crome.. anyways thanks form for responding to my question.

Answer (score 0):

For new Chrome versions you can just put for example `autocomplete="empty"` in your fields and that's it.

Comment: i need my email field blank on load/refresh.

Comment: on form post i hv a if condition which is if ( email == ""). To fulfil the condition i need email field empty

Comment: I understand what you want but for some reason chrome doesn't like autocomplete.

Comment: You could try this: https://gist.github.com/runspired/b9fdf1fa74fc9fb4554418dea35718fe

Answer (score 0):

Chrome ignores `autocomplete="off"`, there is only working on form tag.

You could change autocomplete attribute to other string

```
<input type="text" name="foo" autocomplete="new-input">
```