# HTML/CSS disable autocomplete suggest for a pincode input

Tags: html, css, autocomplete

I am working on an application where a user has to enter a pincode after logging in. This pincode has to be obfuscated so I have made the input field of type password. However now I have run into the problem that if I click on the input field chrome seems to suggest autocompleting this field with a password via its password manager.

[Popup when clicking on the pincode input field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n37h0.png)

Obviously I don't want to autocomplete the password into a pincode input but I have failed to find a way to stop chrome from suggesting this. I have tried to not make it a password input but instead set text-security myself but this seems less secure/future-proof and I couldn't get that to work on firefox. I've tried giving the input field random id's but this did not stop chrome from suggesting to autofill it with a password.

The actual password field for for credentials and the pincode input field are in two different forms, but on the same url. I assume it's going wrong since the password manager sees two type password fields on the same url, but I'm not really able to change either of these.

How would I go about stopping the password manager from suggesting a password to be autocompleted in a pincode input field?

**Edit (why it isn't a dupe):** Users have suggested putting a random string in the autocomplete field and I have tried this before but it has not worked nor does it work now unfortunately. I have made an example of the behaviour that I am seeing in JSFiddle (pretty minimalistic but it showcases the problem perfectly). However I can not seem to get chrome to save passwords from snippets so I can't seem to showcase the problem within a snippet. https://jsfiddle.net/mwy6xjbz/2/

How to reproduce problem in the fiddle:

1) [Fill in a username and password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YArwj.png).

2) [Save the username and password via chromes password manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPUCG.png)

3) Click on the pin input field (you can even reload the page if you like) and [see how chrome suggest filling in the password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrJAQ.png), despite the input field for the pincode having `autocomplete='no-autocomplete-please'` nor it being the actual password field.

Comment: Post the code that you have worked..

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=468153

Comment: Thank you for the link and I did come across that before I posted the question but the resolution there did not seem to work for me.

Comment: You can click the `[<>]` snippet editor and show the issue here, rather than jsfiddle

Comment: I have edited the question to showcase the problem using a jsfiddle, apologies for not being able to get it to work with a snippet.

Comment: this should not have been marked as a duplicate as there is an ongoing issue particularly in google chrome and the solution keeps changing.

Answer (score 0):

add autocomplete="off" attribute inside your tag

like

```
<input type="password" autocomplete="off" />
```

Comment: Chrome seems to ignore autocomplete="off" completely as far as I am aware.

Comment: yes you may replace off with any random string like nope or no-suggestion

Comment: autocomplete="off" or any other value is not working after the update from Chrome

Comment: After Chrome version 72.XX, this fix does not work. Find the lastest fixe here https://stackoverflow.com/a/55045439/1161998