# How to remove recommended data from Input box in html

Tags: html

I created a chat system using php.

For the chat box I used Input text box. wheneve I try to send a message, previous msg that I sent start to show on top of the box.[the demo of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Zofb.png)

as you can see that previous 2  messages are showing on top of the input box.

I don't want this.

I have used thia code for input

```
    <input style="padding:4px;" id="msgCont" type="text" placeholder="Message..." class="inputText w95" />
```

please help me to remove this recommend data.

Comment: Just use ```autocomplete="off"```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn off the autocomplete attribute:

```
<input style="padding:4px;" id="msgCont" type="text" placeholder="Message..." class="inputText w95" autocomplete="off"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the [`autocomplete="off"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete) attribute:

```
<input 
  autocomplete="off"
  style="padding:4px;"
  id="msgCont"
  type="text"
  placeholder="Message..."
  class="inputText w95"
/>
```

Comment: `autocomplete="off"` doesn't work in the more recent versions of Chrome

Answer (score 0):

This is quite simple. In the `HTML` you can put this: `autocomplete="nofill"`. `autocomplete="off"` doesn't work in the more recent versions of Chrome. Check out [this StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30053167/autocomplete-off-vs-false) post.

Comment: `autocomplete="nofill"` is not in the MDN spec at all, though. I don't think Firefox or other browsers would honor that unknown value.

Comment: @AKX You're right with the MDN, but when it comes to the browsers your wrong. It seems to work in all browsers. This isn't just the case with `nofill` but also with `true` and `false`

Answer (score 0):

It'll be fixed as soon as you put in a single code. This is it.

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" />
```

Or if you're using a formtag, you can insert it into the formtag.

```
<form autocomplete="off">
  <input type="text" />
</form>
```