# Disabling Chrome 84 form autofill

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I am trying to disable **Chrome version 84** autofill from one of my form fields and I have many methods which none seem to work:

I have tried these:

```
<!-- setting autocomplete to random value other than on or off -->
<input autocomplete="xyz" type="text"/>

<!-- setting autocomplete to random value other than on or off in form and input -->
<form autocomplete="xyz">
<input autocomplete="xyz" type="text"/>
</form>

<!-- setting autocomplete to chrome-off -->
<input autocomplete="chrome-off" type="text"/>
```

I have also tried creating hidden elements as well to "trick" Chrome but I wasn't able to do that.
I have done all methods mentioned in these posts:

[Autocomplete off vs false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30053167/autocomplete-off-vs-false)

[Chrome ignores autocomplete="off"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374442/chrome-ignores-autocomplete-off/32578659)

I am out of options am I missing something?

Comment: is it a login form? most browsers dropped support for turning it off

Comment: No its a simple search box in my navbar, I have already tried setting the `type=" search"` doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution which seems opposite of has been recommended although I do not know if this will be the case for everyone:

```
<!-- simply set the type to search and then set autocomplete to off -->
<input type="search" autocomplete="off"/>
```

If you  wish to remove the `x` as well for the input field you can do:

```
input[type=search]::-ms-clear {  display: none; width : 0; height: 0; }
input[type=search]::-ms-reveal {  display: none; width : 0; height: 0; }

/* clears the 'X' from Chrome */
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-results-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-results-decoration { display: none; }
```

Resource: https://blog.maximerouiller.com/post/remove-the-x-from-internet-explorer-and-chrome-input-type-search/