# XAMPP automatically adds values to input fields or something like that

Tags: php, html, xampp

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="password" name="pass">
</form>
```

It's really strange but when i run xampp my input fields are automatically set if i add `type="password"` to one of them. I never entered any data inside the form. If i use built-in php server the problem is gone. Same for laravel built-in server.

I tried to reinstall xampp and created a new file inside

> C:/xampp3/htdocs/aihara/index.php

No use.

Comment: I would have thought it was more likely your browser automatically filing in the values.

Comment: i tried autocomplete=off too

Comment: Clear browsing data with `Autofill form-data `

Comment: Are you using Chrome? Some people reported problems with `autocomplete="off"` in Chrome. See this [SO thread about autocomplete off vs false vs other values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30053167/autocomplete-off-vs-false) -- From [developer.mozilla.org recommendations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion) can you try: `autocomplete="new-password"`?