# How I can autocomplete off

Tags: html

I use this but autocomplete is not working, any one can help me

```
<input type="email" id="email" name="email" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30053167/autocomplete-off-vs-false

Comment: I guess you have to use it on a ```<form>``` tag and wrap the inputs in the form. Works flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<input type="text" id="email" name="email" autocomplete="off" onclick="()=>{
document.getElementById('email').type='email'
}">
```

Comment: You probably have to use single quotes in the onclick attribute in order to get this to work.