# Chrome auto-fill are filling the wrong text inputs

Tags: php, google-chrome, autofill

I am coding a php website.  My issue is really on the profile page.  The auto-fill is putting my email address where I have an input for the street address.  Here is an image of what I mean.

[image: Auto-Fill Image]

```
 <input type="text" name="txtstreetaddress" id="txtstreetaddress" placeholder="Street Address" tabindex="6" value="<?php echo $address ?>" style="font-family: 'Ubuntu';margin-top: -30px;font-size: 14px;height: 30px;width: 280px;" autocomplete="off" value="">
```

I also have the Form set to autocomplete="off"

Comment: Have you made sure that your autofill information in your Chrome profile is correct?

Comment: You're setting `value="<?php echo $address ?>"` which probably is your *email*-address

Answer (score 0):

You got to use `autocomplete="false"` instead of "off".

If this still does not work (what i don't expect) you can handle it by putting two fake-fields at the beginning of your form like the following ones:

```
<input style="display:none" type="text" name="fakeusernameremembered"/>
<input style="display:none" type="password" name="fakepasswordremembered"/>
```

Comment: According to https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input/text it's `autocomplete = on/ off/ default`

Comment: Double-Checked: You're right! Did some further investigation on the Question: It's not about autocomplete. What happened on the picture above is chromes autofill, which is not affected by autocomplete="off". the fake fields seem to be the only workaround at the moment.

Comment: Fake-fields do not work since Chrome does not autofill hidden fields

Comment: Hiding the fields doesn't work anymore. You need to hide them without actually hiding them, so do something like this: `<div style="overflow:hidden;width:0;height:0;"><input type="text" name="username"></div>`

Answer (score -2):

check my answer here.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62943913/12332625

Use labels for the input fields. I think your problem is that you have 2 input fields on one line. `<label for="email">Your email</label>` etc. should fix your problem.

Like this:

```
<label for="txtstreetaddress">Street Address:</label> <input type="text" name="txtstreetaddress" id="txtstreetaddress" placeholder="Street Address" tabindex="6" value="<?php echo $address ?>" style="font-family: 'Ubuntu';margin-top: -30px;font-size: 14px;height: 30px;width: 280px;" autocomplete="off" value="">
```