# Chrome/Safari autofilling with incorrect address no matter what I change

Tags: forms, google-chrome, safari

I have had an issue for some time now where if I fill out any online forms with my address, the floor/apartment number (or address line 2) gets autofilled with something different from what was in the text box when I click the submit button.

Obscuring my actual information for obvious reasons, but I will say that no matter what I fill in to any online form for my address, it always comes out as "Fl 10B". All other fields remain the same.

```
Name: Blah Blahberson
Address: Address Road
Address Line 2: Apt 25C
City: City1
State: State1
Zip: 12345
```

When I click submit for my address, the confirmation window will show:

```
Name: Blah Blahberson
Address: Address Road
Address Line 2: Fl 10B
City: City1
State: State1
Zip: 12345
```

This issue happens both on my Mac (macOS High Sierra) AND my PC (Windows 10) in Google Chrome, and I have even tested it on my Macbook using Safari and the issue persists. It persists across several different websites, so I know the issue is not a specific site.

I have tried deleting all of my saved addresses in Chrome, restarting my computer, logging out and back in, deleting all of my cookies in both Chrome and Safari, clearing my browser history, etc. No matter what I do the issue persists. Does anyone have any clue what is going on here?

Edit: I just tried to fill out the same form on my iPhone, and even that has the same issue

Answer (score 1):

If you need to avoid auto-filling the form with address details, try setting some misc text with `autocomplete` attribute of the form `<input>` tags (setting `autocomplete="off"` won't work)

ex : `autocomplete="false"`, `autocomplete="nahnah"`

Or else try setting the correct value for the `autocomplete` as mentioned in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete#values)

```
autocomplete="address-line2"
```

if you want to find the actual attribute that chrome actually tries to auto-fill with a particular input [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54746641/4423695) answer might be helpful.

Comment: If the problem were just in Chrome then it would make sense, but this is auto filling even in Safari on my Macbook which makes no sense to me