# Why isn't there a working solution for disabling browser caching?

Tags: html, forms, google-chrome, autocomplete, field

I have a registration (unique) form for which I want to disable the memory of the email and password field so that it won't autocomplete. Now I tried all methods. `autocomplete=off` for the fields, explicitly setting the field to blank as well as disabling caching with meta tag.

Nothing worked. Why is nothing possible when it is easy to understand that we need this functionality?

Comment: Caching has nothing to do with autocomplete.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374442/chrome-browser-ignoring-autocomplete-off this one could help you, but is terrible.

Comment: @Heru-Luin It worked for me. So my question is a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it is easy to understand that we need this functionality

Wrong.  You should not try to prevent the user from using useful features.

Browsers removed support for `autocomplete="off"` precisely because of people like you, who made the autocomplete feature less useful.

Comment: In most cases I would agree, but disabling it definitely has it's place

Comment: I found a (bad) working method. Add two dummy hidden input fields in the beginning of the form.