# Issue of saved password features of browsers on add users form

Tags: html, forms

I have one login form which I saved user name and password of my credentials. I have a form which admin can add user but saved password already show on my form and admin is force to delete those before filling form.

I have tried with solutions like:

```
autocomplete="off"
```

But was not successful solutions.

how can i prevent to showing saved username and password on add user form.

Comment: last version of firefox and chrome. i want to disabled showing saved password and username on my add user form

Comment: @Majid, Use my solution this will work

Comment: @DeepakDholiyan thank you. i commented on your post, i am looking for HTML solution.

Comment: Did you try `autocomplete="false"`?

Comment: @Kittsil yes did not work

Answer (score -1):

autocomplete="off" does not works for saved passwords.

You can use below step for this problem

1) Add readonly attribute to username and password

2) Now On onclick, onmouseover and onfocus remove this attribute.

```
  <input type="text" readonly="" onmouseover="$(this).removeAttr('readonly')" onclick="$(this).removeAttr('readonly')" onfocus="$(this).removeAttr('readonly')" value="" name="frmUsername" class="form-control">
```

You can also try first answer solution given at below links

[Chrome Browser Ignoring AutoComplete=Off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374442/chrome-browser-ignoring-autocomplete-off)

Comment: Thank you, At this time I am looking for a solution which HTML has that by default.

Comment: I have tried on this many solution. This is the only solution for this

Comment: autocomplete="off"  does not work for saved password

Comment: Here I used javascript so no need to include any jquery file

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: Unfortunately i could not found solution till now

Comment: This is 100% correct and tested solution. Down vote is realy not good here. This is very embrassing