# Auto complete won't turn off? HTML Textbox/ Password fields

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to make it so the forms on my login/ registration pages won't preload data already entered. I've tried using autocomplete although some research on here tells me that this is ignored by Chrome? So I was wondering how else I can get around this issue?

Code:

```
<h3>USERNAME:</h3>
<input type='textbox' autocomplete='off' name='usernamereg' value='<?php     echo $_POST['usernamereg'] ?>'>
```

I want the bottom 2 fields to not have the pre-entered information:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSUAa.png)

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome Browser Ignoring AutoComplete=Off](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374442/chrome-browser-ignoring-autocomplete-off)

Comment: You should give value='' empty..

Answer (score 0):

For some weird reason, Google Chrome seems to ignore autocomplete rules in forms. Google Chrome also seems to only autofill the first occurrence of a `username`/`password` field. Try the following for the password field:

```
<input type="text" style="display:none!important">
<input type="text" autocomplete="null" name="usernamereg" value="<?php echo $_POST['usernamereg'] ?>">

<input type="password" style="display:none!important">
<input type="password" autocomplete="null" name="whatevername" value="<?php echo $yourvariable ?>">
```

Comment: Wait, this is a user registration form, isn't it?

Comment: Try going to chrome://settings/passwords and removing the password that is listed under your website.

Answer (score 0):

You have saved username and password in you browser. So It fill fetch from the browser autocomplete. If you clear cache and saved password. It wont come... I face this same issue... After clearing those things. It works fine... Hope it work for you too...

Answer (score 0):

write autocomplete="off" in your form tag

```
<form method="" action="" autocomplete="off" > 
</form>
```

Hope this will work