# Firefox/chrome End user save password keep populating input's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, firefox

I have several places in my web app that allows the end user to create new users. However if the user upon logging in the first times opt to have chrome/Firefox save there credentials it will from then on our put there login password in the `<input type="password">` fields. This is not a problem with autocomplete with is a problem with the browsers native function to save end user login information then try to populate input fields for the user.

Is there a way to over ride this.

Comment: possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38144955/how-to-disable-saved-password-features-of-browsers-on-add-users-form Kinda hacky, but seems to do the trick.

Comment: @KevinB this is a very hacky way of doing this. My web application is far to large and complicated to throw something like this in and hope nothing happens

Comment: well... there's also the point here in that you really shouldn't be allowing users to set other user's passwords... If you omitted the password field, does it still autofill the username?

Comment: @KevinB not in this case :)

Comment: @KevinB the browser looks for an input field type="password" and then tries to auto fill as much information as it can, in this case an email as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicate of [This question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill)

Simply create a couple of fields and make them hidden with "display:none".

Example:

```
<!-- fake fields are a workaround for chrome autofill getting the wrong fields -->
<input style="display:none" type="text" name="fakeusernameremembered"/>
<input style="display:none" type="password" name="fakepasswordremembered"/>
```

Then put your real fields underneath.

Comment: yeah thats what im reading however theres gotta be a more bug proof way of doing this

Comment: I don't think there is.
Security always looks like bugs in chrome, check 403 forbidden alert box for example.