# Chrome Browser Hiding Background Image In Input Box On Autofill

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have login popup on a webpage. The login form contains two fields username and password. Both input fields have  a background image (shown with help of CSS).

But during login, autofill of chrome browser populates  data in the form fields and hides  background image , image is shown on the extreme left of the input fields. So, its not like text  is overriding image.

I  read other answers suggesting moving image out of the input fields. I need image in input box only.
What CSS or JS trick can be used here to show background image in input box even on autofill of Chrome browser?

Here is what I am trying:

HTML:

```
<input class="form-text-inputs"
       type="text"
       name="password"
       ng-pattern="ctrl.usernameRegex"
       placeholder="{{'USER.PASSWORD_PLACEHOLDER' | translate}}"
       ng-model="ctrl.password"
       maxlength="50"
       required>
```

CSS:

```
input[type = 'password'] {
    background-image: url(../assets/images/passwordimage.png) ;

    padding-left: 36px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the solution.This is  how it looks now.

```
    input[type = 'password'] {
background-image: url(../assets/images/password.png) ;
-webkit-appearance: none;
padding-left: 36px;}

input[type = 'password']:-webkit-autofill {
background-image: url(../assets/images/password.png) ;


-webkit-appearance: none;
padding-left: 36px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px white inset !important;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can turn off the browser's in-built autocomplete by adding `autocomplete="off"` to the input element.

```
<input class="form-text-inputs"
       type="text"
       name="username"
       ng-pattern="ctrl.usernameRegex"
       placeholder="{{'USER.USERNAME_PLACEHOLDER' | translate}}"
       ng-model="ctrl.username"
       maxlength="50"
       required autocomplete="off">
```

Also, the CSS selector is wrong. It should be `input[type=text]` instead of `input[type=username]`

Comment: Setting autocomplete="off" won't play well with chrome usually. Checkout this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374442/chrome-browser-ignoring-autocomplete-off