# How to avoid Chrome hide background image and color over an autofill input?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

**Chrome Browser** auto-fill removed effect of `background-color` and `background-image` from `Username` and `Password` input fields.

**Before autocomplete**

[image]

**After autocomplete**

[image]

But **Chrome Browser** autocomplete hide my icons from inputs and also changed my `background-color`. So i need my icons stay on inputs as it is.

It is possible to stop **Chrome Browser** from change background color of fields and hide images?

```css
.form-section .form-control {
 border-radius: 4px;
 background-color: #f7f8fa;
 border: none;
 padding-left: 62px;
 height: 51px;
 font-size: 16px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: left 17px center;
}

.form-section .form-control:focus {
 -webkit-box-shadow: none;
 box-shadow: none;
}

.form-section .form-group {
 margin-bottom: 21px;
}

.form-section .form-control[type="email"] {
 background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhx3w.png');
}

.form-section .form-control[type="password"] {
 background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/910l0.png');
}

.form-btn {
  padding:10px;
    background-color: #65a3fe;
    border: none;
    color: #ffffff;    
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-section">
    <form>                                 
        <div class="form-group">
            <input title="Email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Your email address" value="">
  </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input title="Password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Your Password">
  </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-btn">Log in</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: if you give us some code example we can try help you , without code is hard to tell you what to do

Comment: Could you not stop chrome autocomplete?

Comment: you can use `autocomplete="off"` in input tag.

Comment: Did you use  !important in your css?

Comment: Check i shared code and double click on mail input and select one from below suggested list , you can find issue.

Comment: does this answer your question 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781549/removing-input-background-colour-for-chrome-autocomplete

Comment: and try to use `input-group` from bootstrap

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38551560/chrome-browser-hiding-background-image-in-input-box-on-autofill

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Here you can use any color e.g. `white`, `#DDD`, `rgba(102, 163, 177,
>   0.45)`.

For Background:  `transparent` won't work here so please use colors.

```
/* Change the white to any color ;) */
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover, 
input:-webkit-autofill:focus, 
input:-webkit-autofill:active  {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px white inset !important;
}
```

for text color:

```
/*Change text in autofill textbox*/
input:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-text-fill-color: yellow !important;
}
```

**Your Solution:**(for above case)

Use separate `div` for icon and for `input`

```css
.form-section .form-control {
 
 font-size: 16px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 9px;
}

.form-section .form-control:focus {
 -webkit-box-shadow: none;
 box-shadow: none;
}

.form-section .form-group {
 margin-bottom: 21px;
}

.icon-email {
 background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhx3w.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    width: 30px;
    height: auto;
}

.icon-pass {
 background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/910l0.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    width: 30px;
    height: auto;
}

.form-btn {
  padding:10px;
    background-color: #65a3fe;
    border: none;
    color: #ffffff;    
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.input-txt{
    padding-left: 5px;
    float:left;
    border-left:none;
    outline:none ;
    border: none;
    background-color: #f7f8fa;
}

.custom-input {
    display: flex; 
    border-radius: 4px;
 background-color: #f7f8fa !important;
 border: none;
 height: 51px;
}
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover, 
input:-webkit-autofill:focus, 
input:-webkit-autofill:active  {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px #f7f8fa inset !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-section">
    <form>                                 
        <div class="form-group custom-input">
        <div class='icon-email'></div>
            <input title="Email" type="email" class="form-control input-txt" name="email" placeholder="Your email address" value="">
  </div>
        <div class="form-group  custom-input">
        <div class='icon-pass'></div>
            <input title="Password" type="password" class="form-control input-txt" name="password" placeholder="Your Password">
  </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-btn">Log in</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: When i use this solution its hide my icons. please check code i shared in question.

Comment: Can we use background-img as image in `img` tag?

Comment: @JigneshPanchal I updated my answer please have a look and do let me know if you got any issue.

Comment: But is it possible stop chrome to override it's css.

Comment: Not exactly, Only you can try some hacks and also use '!important' to override the style you want to make that on high prior for ref https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill

Answer (score 1):

You **CAN NOT** Override the autocomplete code, since it's being controlled by **user agent stylesheet**, take a look at [cascading-order](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascading-order) to know more.

**Here is the code** (*i've copied from google chrome*) that is making your icons disappear on autocomplete, just *in case you were wondering*:

```
input:-internal-autofill-selected {
      background-color: rgb(232, 240, 254) !important;
      background-image: none !important;
      color: -internal-light-dark-color(black, white) !important;
    }
```

**So what now?** If you are intent on **solving icons disappearing** problem here is a **hack** that you can do it for you:

```css
.form-section .form-control {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #f7f8fa;
  border: none;
  padding-left: 62px;
  height: 51px;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left 17px center;
}

.form-section .form-control:focus {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.form-section .form-group {
  margin-bottom: 21px;
  position: relative;
}

.form-icon {
  position: absolute;
  left: 16px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.form-section .form-control[type="password"] {
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/910l0.png');
}

.form-btn {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #65a3fe;
  border: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-section">
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input title="Email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Your email address" value="">

    <img class="form-icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhx3w.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input title="Password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Your Password">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-btn">Log in</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check if this works for you. I made some changes on your code.

You can check in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/quethzel/wz762ay0/4/)

```
<div class="form-section">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group control">
      <input title="Email" type="email" class="form-control email" name="email" placeholder="Your email address" value="">
      <span class='input-icon'></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group control">
      <input title="Password" type="password" class="form-control pass" name="password" placeholder="Your Password">
      <span class='input-icon'></span>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-btn">Log in</button>
  </form>
</div>


.form-section .form-control {
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #f7f8fa;
    border: none;
    padding-left: 62px;
    height: 51px;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left 17px center;
}

.form-section .form-control:focus {
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.form-section .form-group {
    margin-bottom: 21px;
}

.form-btn {
  padding:10px;
    background-color: #65a3fe;
    border: none;
    color: #ffffff;    
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.control {
    position: relative;
}

.email .pass {
    padding-left: 35px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.email ~ .input-icon {
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhx3w.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-position: center center;
    width: 22px;
    height: 14px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 8px;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin: auto;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;

}
.pass ~ .input-icon {
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/910l0.png');  
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-position: center center;
    width: 22px;
    height: 14px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 8px;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin: auto;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

[image: jsfiddle example]

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Change the white to any color ;) */
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover, 
input:-webkit-autofill:focus, 
input:-webkit-autofill:active  {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px white inset !important;
}


/*Additionally, you can use this to change the text color:*/

/*Change text in autofill textbox*/
input:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-text-fill-color: yellow !important;
}
```

Credit to @Fareed Alnamrouti
 from [Removing input background colour for Chrome autocomplete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781549/removing-input-background-colour-for-chrome-autocomplete)

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this code, hope this will helpful to you

```css
.form-section .form-control {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #f7f8fa;
  border: none;
  padding-left: 62px;
  height: 51px;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left 17px center;
}

.form-section .form-control:focus {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.form-section .form-group {
  margin-bottom: 21px;
}

.form-section .form-control[type="email"] {
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhx3w.png');
}

@-webkit-keyframes autofill_email {
  to {
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhx3w.png');
  }
}

.form-section .form-control[type="email"]:-webkit-autofill {
  -webkit-animation-name: autofill_email;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
}

.form-section .form-control[type="password"] {
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/910l0.png');
}

@-webkit-keyframes autofill_pass {
  to {
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/910l0.png');
  }
}

.form-section .form-control[type="password"]:-webkit-autofill {
  -webkit-animation-name: autofill_pass;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
}

.form-btn {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #65a3fe;
  border: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section class="py-4">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="form-section">
      <form>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input title="Email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Your email address" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input title="Password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Your Password">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-btn">Log in</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

If you want remove background color, then add default background-color in keyframe style