# Autocomplete is not available in my asp:textBox

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, autocomplete, passwords, autofill

I have this textBox:

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtInsuredPassword" TabIndex="1" runat="server" Width="157px"
          TextMode="Password" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" >
    </asp:TextBox>
```

AutocompleteType ="Disabled" is not working on chrome and I found that I have to use autocomplete="Off", but I cannot find it in my control ... any suggestions?

[image]

As you can see here autocomplete is not available

Comment: @hal what is the purpose of using the `AUTOCOMPLETE` ?

Comment: @Webruster I have a login form, whenever I enter credentials and press on login button and save those crendentials, a new page is displayed and the first textBox with textMode password is catching and displaying my entered pass, that's why I am using autocomplete to disable the autofill

Comment: @hal are you flexible to use alternative solution which fixes ur problem?

Comment: I would appreciate any help

Comment: @hal please try my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
autocomplete="Off", but I cannot find it in my control ... any suggestions
```

Just place it on your asp.net text control and will appear on the html rendered page.

So your code will be as:

```
   <asp:TextBox ID="txtInsuredPassword" TabIndex="1" runat="server" Width="157px"
          TextMode="Password" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" autocomplete="Off" >
    </asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: I added autocomplete="Off" , it is not firing any error but on chrome it still saves the password

Comment: @H.Al check this answer for a solution on that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374442/chrome-browser-ignoring-autocomplete-off

Answer (score 1):

In the New page inside your Mark Up before your `txtInsuredPassword` try to keep this `input` type so that your problem will be solved

```
  <input style="display: none" type="password" name="fakepassword" />
```

At the time of DOM loading , broswer would first check for the inputtype `password` and autofill it with the `Passowrd` so we are just trying to avoiding it by keeping a `fakepassword` as  input type

Comment: I have tried your solution, it is working only when I remove display none, otherwise I am facing the same issue. I used visibility:hidden with 0px for width and height, and it works normally. Any idea about why on visibility:hidden it works and display: none does not?

Comment: <input type="password" style="visibility:hidden;width:0px;height:0px" name="fakepassword" />  this is my solution, I did not add anything for the real password, neither autocomplete ...

Comment: @H.Al i need your complete markup how you are keeping

Answer (score -1):

Did you try [this](https://forums.asp.net/post/2592912.aspx) answer? If you're using firefox then you have to use:  autocomplete="off" or from code behind:

```
Textbox1.Attributes.Add("autocomplete", "off");
```

Comment: I updated my question so you can see better in the added picture what I mean by autocomplete is not available, anyway I tried to use it in code behind and still not working ...

Comment: autocomplete is attribute of html textbox, not asp.net specific textbox. that's why it's not showing in your suggestion.