# Auto-Complete Off is not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, razor

I am trying to disable google password autocomplete field in password text-box in chrome browser. I tried  autocomplete off but that doesn't work then I tried auto complete : "new password" that also doesn't work. Suggest me any solution for this problem.
Thanks in advance.
here is my code

i tried
autocomplete="new-password"

Comment: you are talking about HTML autocomplete attribute right?

Comment: Please follow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374442/chrome-browser-ignoring-autocomplete-off. This question might be duplicate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome Browser Ignoring AutoComplete=Off](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374442/chrome-browser-ignoring-autocomplete-off)

Comment: I had tried all the above but problem is still the same...

Comment: @RanaGhosh yes i am talking about html autocomplete attribute on chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to disable it -- at this point only thing i the  `autocomplete='off'` doesn't work

i would try this -- 
set the password box with a value on the pageload

```
$("input[type='password']").val(" ");
```

on focus set the value to empty

```
$(document).on("focus","input[type='password']",function(){                  
    $(this).val('');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use a trick. Chrome always track first `<input type="password">` and the previous `<input>`. So  add this:

```
<input style="display:none">
<input type="password" style="display:none">
```

To just after `<form>` tag started and the case will be resolved.