# How to turn off HTML input form field suggestions?

Tags: html, form-fields

By suggestions, I mean the drop down menu appear when you start typing, and it's suggestions are based on what you've typed before:

[image: Example]

For example, when I type 'a' in title field, it will give me a ton of suggestions which is pretty annoying.

How can this be turned off?

Comment: `autocomplete="off"`

Comment: It doesn't do the job. I've added it and still when I start typing suggestions will appear.
<input type="text" className="form-control" autocomplete="off" {...title} />(it's React)

Comment: Have you used it in _form_ tag or in _input_ tag?

Comment: If you are using chrome read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374442/chrome-browser-ignoring-autocomplete-off)

Comment: I've used it in form tag.

Comment: Great! I figure that out. it should be autoComplete with capital C.

Comment: Try setting a random Id for your inputs. That does the trick for me.

Comment: Is there a way to turn it off directly from Chrome (or any other browser)?

Answer (score 159, accepted):

What you want is to disable HTML  `autocomplete` Attribute.

> Setting autocomplete="off" here has two effects:
>
> It stops the browser from saving field data for later autocompletion
> on similar forms though heuristics that vary by browser. It stops the
> browser from caching form data in session history. When form data is
> cached in session history, the information filled in by the user will
> be visible after the user has submitted the form and clicked on the
> Back button to go back to the original form page.

Read more on [MDN Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion)

Here's an example how to do it.

```html
<form action="#" autocomplete="off">
  First name:<input type="text" name="fname"><br> 
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br> 
  E-mail: <input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="off"><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

If it's on React framework then use as follows:

```
<input
    id={field.name}
    className="form-control"
    type="text"
    placeholder={field.name}
    autoComplete="off"
    {...fields}/>
```

Link to [react docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html)

**Update 1**

Here's an update to fix some browsers skipping "autocomplete=off" flag.

```html
<form action="#" autocomplete="off">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname" autocomplete="off" readonly onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');"><br> Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" autocomplete="off" readonly onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');"><br> E-mail:
  <input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="off" readonly onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');"><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**Update 2**

Still working on Chrome Version 119.0.6045.200 (Official Build) (64-bit) / Tested on 12/12/2023.

Comment: this method seems not working anymore. Is there now another solution for now?

Comment: @webfacer, now google chrome ignore this flag and some password managing apps also ignores this. However, this could achieve through JavaScript if you're interested.?

Comment: i know but we decided not to use JS because of what if it is turned off? that´s why we decided to use native html. Hmm autocomplete should be always turned off also because of the security issue. see this twitter https://twitter.com/anttiviljami/status/816585860661518336

Comment: I see @webfacer. That is a serious privacy concern indeed. :/

Comment: Autocomplete off is not working on my side. it stills shows the suggestions and fills it

Comment: Every one of these examples is still showing the auto-suggestions for me on Chrome 78.

Comment: autocomplete="off" works in vue project. Thank You!

Answer (score 25):

On Chrome, the only method we could identify which prevented all form fills was to use `autocomplete="new-password"`.  Apply this on any input which shouldn't have autocomplete, and it'll be enforced (even if the field has nothing to do with passwords, e.g. `SomeStateId` filling with state form values).  [See this link on the Chromium bugs discussion for more detail](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=370363#c7).

Note that this only consistently works on Chromium-based browsers and Safari - Firefox doesn't have special handlers for this `new-password` ([see this discussion for some detail](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1119063)).

*Update:* **Firefox is coming aboard!**  Nightly v68.0a1 and Beta v67.0b5 (3/27/2019) feature support for the `new-password` autocomplete attribute, stable releases should be coming on 5/14/2019 [per the roadmap](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Firefox/Roadmap/Updates#2019-04-29).

*Update in 2022:* For input fields with a type of `password`, some browsers are now offering to generate secure passwords if you've specified `autocomplete="new-password"`.  There's currently no workaround if you want to suppress that behavior, but I'll update if one becomes available.

Answer (score 9):

use `autocomplete="off"` attribute

*Quote:**IMPORTANT***

> Put the attribute on the `<input>` element,
>   **NOT** on the `<form>` element

Answer (score 9):

Adding the two following attributes turn off all the field suggestions (tested on Chrome v85, Firefox v80 and Edge v44):

```
<input type="search" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: This worked for me on Vue-2 as of September of 2022

Comment: This combination is the only thing that worked for me. Tested on Chrome v115

Answer (score 4):

I know it's been a while but if someone is looking for the answer this might help. I have used `autocomplete="new-password"` for the password field. and it solved my problem. Here is the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion).

Comment: This worked for me in 2021, `autocomplete="off"` not working with chrome auto saved passwords. For example you have a register form with the same id of "email" and "password" and you saved your credentials in the login window, it offers the user and password in the register form, This "new-password" solved it.

Answer (score 4):

This solution worked for me: Add `readonly` attribute.

> Here's an update to fix some browsers skipping the
> `"autocomplete=off"` flag.
>
> ```
> <input type="text" name="lname" autocomplete="off" readonly onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');">
> ```

Comment: This is not the **best** answer (see [qslabs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70219367/1447509)), but it is a **very clever solution** that inspires thought. +1 for that.

Answer (score 3):

`<input type="text" autocomplete="off">` is in fact the right answer, though for me it wasn't immediately clear.

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion#disabling_autocompletion):

> If a browser keeps on making suggestions even after setting
> autocomplete to off, then you have to change the name attribute of the
> input element.

The attribute does prevent the future saving of data but it does not necessarily clear existing saved data. Thus, if suggestions are still being made even after setting the attribute to `"off"`, either:

- rename the input
- clear existing data entries

Additionally, if you are working in a React context the attribute naturally becomes `autoComplete`.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

autocomplete = "new-password" does not work for me.

I built a React Form.
Google Chrome will autocomplete the form input based on the name attribute.

```
 <input 
  className="scp-remark" 
  type="text" 
  name="remark"
  id='remark'
  value={this.state.remark} 
  placeholder="Remark" 
  onChange={this.handleChange} 
/>
```

It will base on the "name" attribute to decide whether to autofill your form. In this example, name: "remark". So Chrome will autofill based on all my previous "remark" inputs.

```
<input 
  className="scp-remark" 
  type="text" 
  name={uuid()} //disable Chrome autofill
  id='remark'
  value={this.state.remark} 
  placeholder="Remark" 
  onChange={this.handleChange} 
/>
```

So, to hack this, I give name a random value using uuid() library.

```
import uuid from 'react-uuid';
```

Now, the autocomplete dropdown list will not happen.
I use the **id** attribute to identify the form input instead of **name** in the handleChange event handler

```
handleChange = (event) => {
    const {id, value} = event.target;
    this.setState({
        [id]: value,
    })
}
```

And it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue but I eventually end up doing

`<input id="inp1" autocomplete="off" maxlength="1" />`
i.e.,
**autocomplete = 'off'** and suggestions will be disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ReactJS. Then make this as autoComplete="off"

```
<input type="text" autoComplete="off" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing the input field to

```
<textarea style="resize:none;"></textarea>
```

You'll never get autocomplete for textareas.

Comment: When mobile I prefer my keyboard to change depending on input ie. `<input type="email"/>`