# how to disable autosuggestion in input text

Tags: angular

When I type in an input box, my chrome browser automatically provides suggestions based on whatever I typed in this input box before. How can I disable the browser suggestion?

[image]

this is the HTML code:

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstName" formControlName="addUserFirstName" tabindex="2" autocomplete="off" />
```

Comment: did you try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43783924/disable-google-chrome-autocomplete-autofill-suggestion

Comment: it dint work for me

Comment: Inspect your textbox and verify that the autocomplete attribute are added into that control?

Comment: autocomplete attribute is there in the control but still i get the suggestions

Answer (score 0):

`autocomplete` will solve your issue

```
 <input type="text" name="yourName" autocomplete="off">
```

for more info [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43132722/9764133), and check these [MDN WebDocs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion)

Comment: i have added autocomplete="off" in the input but dint work