# Angular HTML Autocomplete="nope" or "off" not working hosted from CDN in chrome

Tags: angularjs, angular, html

I have an input box for surname and I have set Autocomplete = "nope" or even tried "off". For some reason, it's not picking it and always allowing me to select from autocomplete list.

Our Ui app is hosted through CDN. So when I access my app through link [`https:// Xyz. net`] via CDN then Autocomplete off does not work.

but when I access its source link `[https// xyz.azurewebsites. net]` the autocomplete off works for same chrome browsers.

not sure why a change in behavior for the same app in the different source location. 
Note: I tried to purge the content in CDN and it didn't work.

My expected behavior is textbox should not show autocomplete options.

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: this is probably a cache problem, try refreshing with `ctrl + shift + R` and flush the CDN cache.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [autocomplete="new-password" ignored by Chrome 63 in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48150635/autocomplete-new-password-ignored-by-chrome-63-in-windows)

Comment: @MehdiBenmoha Will try and update you

Comment: @AwadMaharoof its not a pasword field and I have tried setting AutoComplete ='nope'.  so based on the suggestion given in the link I used non standard word which should work.. But my case is more peculiar since it works in one domain and not working in it mirror CDN domain..

Answer (score 0):

Since most modern browsers have password management built into them, they do not support this attribute for login fields anymore.

> in-browser password management is generally seen as a net gain for
>   security. Since users do not have to remember passwords that the
>   browser stores for them, they are able to choose stronger passwords
>   than they would otherwise.

You can read more about the reasoning for this behavior and browser support for the attribute [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion#The_autocomplete_attribute_and_login_fields)

On the other hand, there seem to be quite a [few ways](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17719174/1179865) to work around this with various hacks and JavaScript, but I'm unsure if they would work across browsers or cause more complications.

Also to answer you question as to why you see autocomplete only in one domain: I suspect that you may not be seeing the autocomplete suggestions in a specific domain because you may not have clicked "remember password" which would have saved your credentials in the browser.

Comment: First, it is not a password and its surname field I am having the issue. Also, i expect the behavior to be the same because I am testing in the same version of chrome browser.