# Reactjs AutoComplete : 'off'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
<div className={inputContainerClass}>
 <input
                    required
                    autoComplete='off'
                    value={value}
                    type='password'
                    maxLength=15
                />

</div>
```

`autoComplete : 'off'`, `autoComplete: {'off'}`, `autocomplete:{false}`, `<input type="password"  style="display:none">` are not working.

Comment: atleast show your code where you are using it?

Comment: <input
                    required
                    autoComplete={false}
                    value={value}
                    type={type}
                    onChange={this.onChangeHandler}
                    maxLength={maxLength}
                    onFocus={this.handleFocus}
                    onBlur={this.handleBlur}
                    ref={ (input) => {refCb(input)}}
                  

                />

Answer (score 16):

```html
<input name="my-field-name" autoComplete="new-password" />
```

Answer (score 12):

It seems `autoComplete="off"` or `autoComplete="new-password"` works, but after the form is used multiple times it starts saving the values of the field to whatever string you set for the autoComplete.

I've tried numerous strings for the autoComplete, but it always ends up coming back. The best solution I have found for this is to generate a new string for the autoComplete every time. I have been doing that like so with no issues:

```
<input name="field-name" autoComplete={'' + Math.random()} />
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to wrap input tag into form:

```
<form autocomplete="off">
  <input type="text" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `autoComplete="off"`. See working example.

```js
const Element = () => (
  <div>
    <input
      name="email"
      autoComplete="off" />
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Element />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this attribute to your component:

`autoComplete="off" role="presentation"`

Answer (score -1):

It should be `autocomplete="off"`.
But keep in mind that chrome officially ignores this and will use autocomplete anyway. [Take a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374442/chrome-browser-ignoring-autocomplete-off) for some workarounds

Comment: autoComplete is the React version of it, will be transformed to autocomplete on render.