# How to disable Chrome autocomplete feature?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, autofill

We want to disable **autocomplete** in Chrome browser in our React JavaScript application. We have tried a bunch of solutions available on the Internet but nothing worked. `autoComplete=off` is not reliable and so are other ways.

This is really important for us at this moment so can you please suggest us a foolproof way to disable autocomplete in Chrome using React JavaScript?

Secondly, we are using a common control/component for our text boxes and using them everywhere

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome Browser Ignoring AutoComplete=Off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374442/chrome-browser-ignoring-autocomplete-off)

Comment: Can you please tell why autoComplete = "off" is not reliable ? because it works like a charm. Please see the React example I have created here.. https://codesandbox.io/s/72q0z6rp61

Comment: @johnsam Because it is working for few fields while not for the others. Working for 95% scenarios

Comment: @ShivaWahi this is tricky cause not sure what scenario is not working .. if it was reproducible then we can help you out :)

Comment: @johnsam It is tough for me to explain too. On few situations.. sutocomplete"nope" works while somewhere off is working

Answer (score 28):

Do `autocomplete="new-password"` to disable autocomplete. (For React, use `autoComplete`)

> This is a hint, which browsers are not required to comply with. However modern browsers have stopped autofilling  elements with autocomplete="new-password" for this very reason.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion#preventing_autofilling_with_autocompletenew-password)

Comment: thanks it's worked, but how, can anybody explain?

Comment: @yussan
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion#preventing_autofilling_with_autocompletenew-password

Comment: This is invalid jsx

Comment: @AlxVallejo You've to do `<input autocomplete="new-password"/>`

Comment: With this solution you will see "random strong password" suggestions in Chrome. So, you will get rid with one problem and have a new one :D

Answer (score 13):

You can override chrome autofill by add `onFocus` attribute.

```
render()
{
  return <input type="text" name="name" value="this is my input" autoComplete="off" onFocus={this.onFocus} />
}
```

In the `onFocus` method we need to change "autocomplete" attribute through javaScript.

```
onFocus = event => {

   if(event.target.autocomplete)
   {
     event.target.autocomplete = "whatever";
   }

};
```

This solution works for me.

let me know if it works for you ;)

Comment: so far this is the only solution that sees to work for me, that actually makes any sort of sense. Ive tried so many other alternatives. but they sometimes work and sometimes they dont and are unreliable, thanks!

Answer (score 13):

Nothing worked for me including `new-password`, so this is how I did:

```js
onFocus={(event) => {
  event.target.setAttribute('autocomplete', 'off');
  console.log(event.target.autocomplete);
}}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the only thing that worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

I got the same issue with my React project. My solution is to use a random string for autoComplete attribute. Don't use "off", as per [Pim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3516989/pim), you need to set a invalid value to really turn auto completion off. 
Please also note the attribute name has to be autoComplete in React.

Answer (score 2):

When using jsx - you have to camel case attributes; so `autoComplete="new-password"` instead of `autocomplete`.

Answer (score 2):

For me changing just the `autoComplete` attribute to 'new-password' didn't work on its own because the `name` attribute of the field was set to 'password'. As soon as I changed that to something else it worked (in my case for example I used 'devicePassword')

```
<input type='password' name='devicePassword' autoComplete='new-password' />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try not to set the **type** attribute, if you have a password and username, remove both of those input types and voila.. problem solved

Answer (score 0):

The only hack that worked for me is to create hidden input and add random number for the original input name:

```
<input type="text" name="" value="" readOnly={true} style={{display: "none"}}/>
<input
  type="text"
  name={"address " + Math.random()}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround that worked for me:

```js
      onChange={({ target }) => {
          if (target.autocomplete === 'off') {
            setPassword(target.value);
          }
      }}
      onFocus={({ target }) => {
        target.setAttribute('autocomplete', 'off');
      }}
```

The goal is just to define any attribute and check if the value is correct. I chose autocomplete just to make it obvious.

Answer (score 0):

try setting `autocomplete="new-password"` to the `<input type="password">`,
It works.

Answer (score 0):

I solved with

```
<form autoComplete="off">
   <input
     autoComplete="new-off"
   />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use both together ,for email use autoComplete="off" and for password use  autoComplete="new-password"

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for me from the above solutions was to set the password type to text. This prevented the autocomplete on all my form input fields. I then used state and useEffect to dynamically set the type to password as soon as a value was entered for the password.

```
useEffect(() => {
if (!isPasswordVisible) {
  if (password.length > 0) {
    setIsPasswordVisible(true);
  }
}
```

}, [password]);

And in the JSX,

```
<InputField
        id={'signup-password-input'}
        type={isPasswordVisible ? 'password' : 'text'}
        value={password}
        name='devicePassword'
        autoComplete='new-password'
        onChangeFunc={handlePasswordChange}>
        Password
      </InputField>
```

Obviously, I was using an InputField component in this case.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35471486)

Answer (score 0):

put this before your input element

<input name="abc" type="text" style={{display:'none'}}/>