# How to make chrome stop auto filling email address and password in various forms?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am currently working on a project for my client. As soon as I log in to the dashboard and save my password in chrome and then click on a form which adds new vendors to the store, The chrome automatically fills out the email and password of the admin. I tried clearing the browsing data. But it's not feasible because when we launch this project, Our client will also save the password and he/she will face the same issue. I don't really understand what is causing this problem? is it the javascript? or laravel? or chrome? 
Thanks

Comment: try form's `autocomplete="off"` property.Here is the link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion

Comment: thank you but autocomplete="off" didnt worked but this did
<input type="password" name="password" autocomplete="new-password">

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome Browser Ignoring AutoComplete=Off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374442/chrome-browser-ignoring-autocomplete-off)

Answer (score 2):

This question already seems to have a very good answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38961567/6996150

Good luck! :-)

Comment: thank you but autocomplete="off" didnt worked but this did
<input type="password" name="password" autocomplete="new-password">