# Autocomplete="off" not working on app-combobox (Chrome 69)

Tags: html, angular, google-chrome, autocomplete

In my HTML I have a form with a few inputs (type text) and I have 2 `app-comboboxes`. What I would like to do, is set autocomplete off for every field in the form.

I set `autocomplete="off"` for the entire form, works perfectly except on those 2 `dropdowns`.

The `dropdown` works in the following way: if I click on it, a `dropdown` will appear with the full list of options to choose. If I type something, the list will be filtered based on what I typed. My problem is, when the field is empty, and when I click on it, another `dropdown` appears with early typed values, suggestions from Chrome above my `dropdown` with the full list of values. My Google Chrome Version is `69.0.3497`.

I tried to put another `autocomplete="off"` in the `app-combobox` element, which didn't work. Then I tried to write a random string for autocomplete (eg. `autocomplete="nope"`), didn't work again.

I tried every solution which I found, but none of them work.

I would appreciate if someone has a solution for this, or just a clear answer that you cannot do this anymore in Chrome.

Thank you very much!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374442/chrome-ignores-autocomplete-off

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome ignores autocomplete="off"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374442/chrome-ignores-autocomplete-off)