# Browser autofill options overlap angular material autocomplete options

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-material

In angular material, material autocomplete is working fine, but the browser auto fill options are overlapping the material autocomplete popup. How to turn off autocomplete for a specific application without turning off browser auto-fill? Reference image attached.

[image: Example image showing the Material Autocomplete popup overlapping the browser autocomplete]

Comment: autocomplete="off" add in the input field

Comment: i tried this option but its not working

Comment: try `autocomplete="somerandomstringthatdoesntmakesense"`

Comment: https://www.pcworld.com/article/3145489/browsers/how-to-clear-unwanted-autofill-entries-in-google-chrome.html

Comment: its not your code problem its browser problem

Comment: i will try this and update

Comment: @karoluS I tried this, but the latest updated browser are not looking for any parameters in autocomplete property. This is not working nowadays

Comment: @BlueCloud then i got to verify my production applications. I'm using `autocomplete="dont-fill-me-up"` and it prevent autocomplete. What browser are you using?

Comment: Version 65.0.3325.146 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

its also working

```
<input type="search" />
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to prevent browser (especially chrome) autocomplete trigger on an input you'd have to override its default behaviour. Google doesn't respect `autocomplete="off"`. From my experience thing that always worked was using this `autocomplete="randomstring"`, but this is more of a workaround that a solution. You might find more ways to disable it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374442/chrome-ignores-autocomplete-off).

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution using jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#origin_postal").attr("autocomplete", "disabled");
});
```

Comment: Change input type as search "<input type="search" />" its also working