# Prevent Chrome from displaying auto-fill options

Tags: angular, google-chrome, input, autofill, textinput

Recently, when focusing on any text input within our internal Angular applications, Google Chrome will display a box of auto-fill options. It doesn't actually auto-fill the field's value, but the box is interfering with other functionality built into the web app. For instance, we have custom dropdown components that display possible options when focusing on certain text inputs. Google Chrome's options display on top of ours.

I have been unable to find anything related to this seemingly new feature. Can this be disabled at the web application level or would everyone in the firm have to configure their Chrome settings to avoid this?

Comment: There was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168367/angularjs-chrome-autocomplete-dilemma) for Angularjs. Can others say if it has carried over? Maybe this too.. `<input type="search" />` Or.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53477356/495157 (autocomplete disabled)

Comment: Have you tried autocomplete="off"?

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can try `autocomplete="disabled"` or `autocomplete="off"` on your input. Off works for me but for some people with different version I have seen disabled working.