# Adding dynamic attribute to each element of certain kind

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, autocomplete, attributes

Is it possible to add extra attribute with certain value to each element of certain type in the whole application with directive (or different way)?

What I am trying to do is add `autocomplete="off"` to each input form because with recent Google update the browser autofill starts kicking in to different input forms, especially typeaheads shadowing its suggestions.

But I wonder if it is somehow possible to tell angular to use this directive on its own so I don't have to add extra attribute in every `input` element for my own.

Comment: You can find a lot of solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374442/chrome-ignores-autocomplete-off

Comment: I know solution to the problem in my case, looking for possibility to easily decorate it where needed. Anyway thank you.