# Is there any solution for "autocomplete=off" property is not working?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, codeigniter

I have added `autocomplete=off` to my form on the username and password fields, but it's not working.

I have tried many ways for it which are below:

- Add this property in only form
- Add this property in username and password field
- Add `autocomplete=new-password` & `autocomplete=off`

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" name="form1" id="form1" action="test.php" method="post" autocomplete='off'>
```

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: I guess you are using chrome. Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374442/chrome-ignores-autocomplete-off)

Comment: I am using firefox and chrome.
This issue getting in both browser

Comment: try using autocomplete="false" in your input box

Comment: try to add ```autocomplete="off"``` to individual fields.
E.g:
```<input type="text" name="username" autocomplete="off" >```

Comment: I have checked with autocomplete="off" and autocomplete='false' but not getting success
Is there any other ways to resolved it?