# Form autocomplete breaks CSS hover

Tags: html, css, forms, css-selectors, hover

Okay I have a dropdown form for a desktop website.
The user hovers their cursor on a link, the form appears beneath, and they can fill it in.

It is done by means of CSS

```
.subscribe-popup .subscribe-form {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.subscribe-popup:hover .subscribe-form,
.subscribe-popup:active .subscribe-form {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: .95;
}
```

Here is the (edited for brevity) markup

```
<div class="subscribe-popup desktop-only">
    <span class="subscribe-cta">join our mailing list</span>
    <div class="subscribe-form">
        <div id="mc_embed_signup">
            <form  id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate="">
                <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
                    <div class="mc-field-group">
                                <label for="mce-EMAIL">Email Address:  <span class="asterisk">*</span></label>
                                <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL">
                    </div>

                    <!-- etc. -->

                    <div class="clear"><input type="submit" class="button" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe"></div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that Chrome produces a drop down with autocomplete suggestions when I click on any text input in the form. As soon as I hover my mouse over any of the suggestions, the hover is lost on the form, and the form disappears.

Why is that, and how do I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would need more information about your markup, but if you want to keep the autocomplete, maybe you can solve it by simply adding a `:hover` to the form itself, the autocomplete-suggestions are some kind of shadow-DOM of the input, e.g. it would be contained within the form/input itself, so something like this might help:

```css
.subscribe-popup .subscribe-form {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.subscribe-popup:hover .subscribe-form,
.subscribe-popup:active .subscribe-form,
.subscribe-form:hover { /* this is new */
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: .95;
}
```

EDIT: After markup was provided I could fiddle around a bit and it seems the only way of preventing the flickering is to replace the `:hover` on the form with `:focus-within`, that seems to work BUT, no IE (neither the beloved old one nor Edge) do support it, so if you need support for these you likely need JS and then you could handle the entire interaction with JS anyways! OR you could try something like this [polyfill](https://gist.github.com/aFarkas/a7e0d85450f323d5e164) for `:focus-within` (or maybe you don't want IE-users as subscribers anyways? =D)

```css
.subscribe-popup .subscribe-form {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.subscribe-popup:hover .subscribe-form,
.subscribe-popup:active .subscribe-form,
.subscribe-form:focus-within {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: .95;
}
```

```html
<div class="subscribe-popup desktop-only">
    <span class="subscribe-cta">join our mailing list</span>
    <div class="subscribe-form">
        <div id="mc_embed_signup">
            <form  id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate="">
                <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
                    <div class="mc-field-group">
                                <label for="mce-EMAIL">Email Address:  <span class="asterisk">*</span></label>
                                <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL">
                    </div>

                    <!-- etc. -->

                    <div class="clear"><input type="submit" class="button" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe"></div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

a possible **CSS-only** alternative could be to make users of browser with no support for `:focus-within` click the subscribe link instead of just hovering it (which is probably what they will do anyways if nothing happens, just an assumption of course). Requires support for the **general sibling combinator**-selector which is widely [supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator) (IE7+, everybody else):

```css
.form-toggle {
    /* just make it invisible but not inaccessible */
    border: 0;
    clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
    height: 1px;
    outline: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
}

.subscribe-popup .subscribe-form {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.subscribe-popup:hover .subscribe-form,
.subscribe-popup:active .subscribe-form,
.form-toggle:checked ~ .subscribe-form,
.subscribe-form:focus-within {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: .95;
}
```

```html
<div class="subscribe-popup desktop-only">
    <input class="form-toggle" type="checkbox" id="form-toggle" />
    <label class="subscribe-cta" for="form-toggle">join our mailing list</label>
    <div class="subscribe-form">
        <div id="mc_embed_signup">
            <form  id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate="">
                <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
                    <div class="mc-field-group">
                                <label for="mce-EMAIL">Email Address:  <span class="asterisk">*</span></label>
                                <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL">
                    </div>

                    <!-- etc. -->

                    <div class="clear"><input type="submit" class="button" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe"></div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try. I will update my question to include some markup.

Comment: Well I moved show/hide functionality to the form element itself, including your suggestion, and strangely, now, as soon as I hover on the suggestions - instead of the form vanishing, the suggestions do, and the form flickers. So it is more functional but still somewhat broken. Odd.
It makes sense considering what you wrote - the hover event for the autocomplete suggestions propagates up to the form but no further.

Comment: I think what is happening is that when I hover over the suggestion, the hover ends on the parent (.subscribe-popup) and begins on the form. The form flickers and the suggestions dropdown gets lost in transition.

Comment: @Rolf see updated answer above, added a snippet where it works with `:focus-within`

Comment: Thanks. I can get away with no IE but no Edge, not so sure - isn't Edge the up-to-date modern work of art from Microsoft? I can't thank you enough by the way.

Comment: Re Edge, yap, it is their version of modern-art =D...up-to-date, not so much^^... but yeah, then I'd probably recommend you a polyfill that you could remove once support is available...

Comment: @Rolf added a third example that is CSS only and works in all browsers that support the "sibling" selector, which is most...

Comment: I think I'll go with a javascript solution inspired by your hidden checkbox solution. I just toggle a class onclick - so that I can keep autocomplete which can be useful. My other idea was to rewrite the hover functionality by using the javascript bounding box for the popup and watching mousemove on the document to detect whether the cursor is within this box. However I can do simpler.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort and accurate answer.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" autocomplete="off">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

You can stop browser autocomplete by doing the following.

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off">
```

put the `autocomplete="off"` attribute in the input field. Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you. I tried that, it did not seem to work (autocomplete still shows up for some reason), besides I would prefer to find a solution that keeps autcomplete which is a useful feature, however if I fail to find a better solution I would consider this.

Comment: @Rolf check again whether all spellings and syntax are right or not. I've added an example in my answer. You can try that.

Comment: I tried again and again. I am guessing it is a problem with Chrome: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374442/chrome-ignores-autocomplete-off

Comment: Lots of thanks for your time and effort helping me, by the way!

Comment: May be. But I solved this problem in the same way I told here. :(

Comment: As per the URL in my previous comment - changing `autocomplete="off"` to `autocomplete="somerandomstring"` makes it work. However I think I will try to keep autocomplete because some users might want to use it. If that does not work then I will fall back to this.