# Effectively remove autofill and autocomplete in forms

Tags: html, google-chrome

I couldn't find a recent question about this.

It seems that using `[autocomplete=off]` in the input tags, indeed removes the auto-complete suggestions, however the autofill option native to the browser is still there.

Alternatively using `[autocomplete=new-password]` removes the auto-fill option, but not the autocomplete.

Is the only real alternative, create randomized names for each input?

Thanks for the input.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chrome ignores autocomplete="off"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374442/chrome-ignores-autocomplete-off)

Comment: Not really, not only it doesn't have any accepted answers, none of the answers actually addresses the issue, and are from 5 yrs ago.

Comment: from mozilla: "If a browser keeps on making suggestions even after setting autocomplete to off, then you have to change the name attribute of the input element."  [How to turn off form autocompletion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion)