# Is there a way to disable chrome AUTOFILL and AUTOCOMPLETE for angular form?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, google-chrome, autofill

i want to disable autofill and autocomplete google chrome option
i tried variant solution like :

- set ***autocomplete="off"** OR **autocomplete="nope"**
- set input **type="search"**
- an unknown value in the autocomplete like **autocomplete="someThingUnknown"**

is there any solution ?

Comment: Also see [Chrome ignores autocomplete=“off”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374442/chrome-ignores-autocomplete-off)

Comment: @str  i trierd all those solutions and dosn't work for me, and i found a new solution and i want to share it

Comment: Ok i will do it thanks for your advice

Comment: unfortunately i can't add a new answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution :

**1 -** set input type="text" to readonly :

```
<input type="text" [readonly]="inputText" />
```

**2 -**  set input type password to type text and change css to looks like a password input :

html :

```
<input type="text" [readonly]="inputPassword" class="pw-field"/>
```

css :

```
.pw-field{
        -webkit-text-security: disc;
 }
```

**3-** Add a focusEvent to both inputs:

html:

```
<input type="text" [readonly]="inputText" (focus)='focusFunction("text")' />

<input type="text" [readonly]="inputPassword" class="pw-field" (focus)='focusFunction("pw")' />
```

ts:

```
focusFunction(type){
  if(type == "text"){
        this.inputText = false;
        this.inputPassword = true;
    }else if(type == "pw"){
        this.inputText = false;
        this.inputPassword = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm hoping this is helpful. I implemented the following CSS. The Chrome Autofill attempts to load the cached values, but disappears on mouse hover. It's not ideal from a UX perspective, but it's the only thing that seems to work effectively.

`input:-webkit-autofill { display: none; }`