# How to disable the autocomplete option in Angular Forms in Chrome 81

Tags: javascript, html, angular, google-chrome, autocomplete

I have checked all the questions and the solutions provided for disabling the autocomplete option.

I have tried a few of the things like

```
autocomplete="off"
autocomplete="new-password"
autocomplete="randomtext-1222"
autocomplete="nope"
```

But when i used the above things in my form for some of the inputs it disables the autocomplete but for some of the fields, it shows the autocomplete suggestions. If i add autocomplete for that particular input then it enables autocomplete for the other fields

**Field 1**:

```
<input
  digitOnly
  id="ls_ss_speed"
  type="text"
  class="form-control"
  formControlName="ls_ss_speed"
  autocomplete="ls_ss_speed"
  [readonly]="isLSSSSDisabled"
  (input)="onLSSSSChange($event.target.value)"
/>
```

**Field 2**:

```
<input
  digitOnly
  id="rt_ss_speed"
  type="text"
  class="form-control"
  formControlName="rt_ss_speed"
  [readonly]="isRTSSSDisabled"
  (input)="onRTSSSChange($event.target.value)"
/>
```

**Image 1**: When autocomplete is not added to field 2 and when we select field 1 it doesn't show autocomplete suggestions

[image]

**Image 2**: When field 2 is selected displaying autocomplete option

[image]

**Image 3**: When the autocomplete option is added for field 2 and when field 1 is selected it shows autocomplete suggestions only numbers

[image]

**Image 4**: Field 2 also showing the autocomplete suggestions now it shows only numbers

[image]

Comment: Chrome has a history of not allowing the `autocomplete` field to be controlled by the site. This post might help => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374442/chrome-ignores-autocomplete-off