# Can I modify a webapp so Chrome doesn't think chat input is a password field?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I've developed a SIP based webphone app which does SMS, and thus it takes text input.  Whenever I type anything into this field, Chrome pops up with "Change your password; Chrome found the password you just used in a data breach.  We recommend changing this password now."

The field is NOT a protected password field or anything, here is the code:

```
<div id="chatConvSend">
  <input type="text" id="chatInput">
  <input href="#" type="button" id="chatSendBtn" class=btn btn-primary btn-sm" value="Send" onclick="sipMsg('1234')">
</div>
```

Is there something I can do about this field to tell chrome this is NOT a password so it stops popping up all the time?

Comment: `autocomplete="off"` may do it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374442/chrome-ignores-autocomplete-off has other suggestions you could try.

Comment: Good suggestion but that sadly did not work.

Comment: Add a meaningful name to the input would help. Like `name="chat-message"`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, that did not work as well.

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones this solved the problem for me, although my input type <i>was</i> password, so doesn't apply to the problem raised by the OP - might help others though