# How do I disable or prevent input text suggestions for form fields in Edge?

Tags: html, autocomplete, microsoft-edge

How do I prevent a form from suggesting auto-complete values, from previous entries or from saved information in Edge?

[image]

In the above image, the email `input` field is marked as `autocomplete="false"`, but still in the right pane you can see the suggestion is populating.

When I add `autocomplete=disabled` to one field it seems it work, but when I add the attribute to all the inputs, it again starts displaying suggestions for every field.

What is the solution for this?

Comment: This is mostly an issue with the browser, not with your code. In other words you cannot change this behavior; it's the *user's* prerogative to have suggestions show up or not, not yours.

Answer (score 4):

Add the `aria-autocomplete="list"` attribute to the input.

```html
<input type="text" id="FirstName" name="attr1" aria-autocomplete="list">
```

Do not use any other value for the attribute.

Comment: Just an FYI I've added in 2 lines in my jquery.
 $this.attr("autocomplete", 'off');
                $this.attr("aria-autocomplete", 'list');

Does the same trick!

Comment: I tried in HTML directly with the `autocomplete` attribute and it doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah, same here. My Jquery has the autocomplete off and also your aria-autocomplete=" list" solution. I guess I'll keep having both - hopefully chrome/edge will fix the issue and respect the autocomplete off flag. (like they should)

Comment: I noticed that it's only an issue with Edge, not Chrome.

Comment: Weird loads have people have said that it's an issue with Chrome and basically todo with the engine that both Chrome/Edge run on.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374442/chrome-ignores-autocomplete-off

Comment: I guess that was the case in the past, but it seems to be fixed in Chrome. I guess that autocomplete part is a Edge specific part, not part of the engine.

Answer (score 3):

According to your description, I reproduced the problem. I think your issue is caused by the "*Save and fill personal info*" setting being enabled in Edge.

If you navigate to `edge://settings/personalinfo` and disable this feature, you can see this behavior no longer exists.

Or you can also click the "*Manage personal info*" option in the picture you provided, and then disable it.

I did some simple tests and found that if you need to solve the problem from the code, you need to modify the `name` attribute of the form's related field.

Like this（do not use attribute values like `name` or `email`... and maybe there are others I am not aware of):

```
<label for="attr1">attr1:</label>
<input type="text" id="FirstName" name="attr1">

<label for="attr2">attr2 :</label>
<input type="text" id="LastName" name="attr2">

<label for="attr3">attr3 :</label>
<input type="email" id="Email" name="attr3" autocomplete="off">

<input type="submit">
```

I don't recommend this, because good naming helps you understand and maintain the code. Using proper attributes like `name` and `email` also helps your code be more accessible for screen readers or other assistive technology.