# Difference between autocomplete = "disabled" and autocomplete = "off"

Tags: javascript, html, css, tags

What is the difference between autocomplete = "disabled" and autocomplete = "off", when I use autocomplete = "off", I'm still able to get a drop down and able to fill emails. I'm using edge, below are screenshots for reference

[image: autocomplete = "off"]

[image: autocomplete = "disabled"]

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is that `autocomplete="off"` is largely ignored in modern browsers - primarily due to password managers etc.. In your case `autocomplete="disabled"` is working because your browser doesn't recognize this value. So you may be happy that random value works for you as this solution sometimes doesn't work either.

Here are some other solutions to this problem:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374442/chrome-ignores-autocomplete-off"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374442/chrome-ignores-autocomplete-off%22)

Answer (score -1):

It is form attribute autocomplete="off" and autocomplete="some string" for input field disabled

```
<form autocomplete="off">
    <input id="email" autocomplete="email" name="email" type="email">
</form>
```

Comment: I think it will work

Comment: @Vamsi Simhadri  It will work. I checked worked from my side.