# Auto Completed Is off but browser still suggesting

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to make auto complete input field off but crome still suggesting.

```
<input
  disabled={disabled}
  type={type}
  autoComplete="off"
  className={`ip__input ${className}`}
  {...(register && register(name))}
  {...rest}
  maxLength={fieldLimit || 100}
/>
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chrome ignores autocomplete="off"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374442/chrome-ignores-autocomplete-off)

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=587466